# Javascript function to convert color names to hex codes

Tags: javascript, colors

Is there a built-in function that would convert a color by name into its hex representation?
Like I want to pass 'white' and receive '#FFFFFF'. I really want to avoid coding all hundred if's myself :)

Answer (score 139, accepted):

No, but using the [list here](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_names.asp) you could create one.  Something like this:

```
function colourNameToHex(colour)
{
    var colours = {"aliceblue":"#f0f8ff","antiquewhite":"#faebd7","aqua":"#00ffff","aquamarine":"#7fffd4","azure":"#f0ffff",
    "beige":"#f5f5dc","bisque":"#ffe4c4","black":"#000000","blanchedalmond":"#ffebcd","blue":"#0000ff","blueviolet":"#8a2be2","brown":"#a52a2a","burlywood":"#deb887",
    "cadetblue":"#5f9ea0","chartreuse":"#7fff00","chocolate":"#d2691e","coral":"#ff7f50","cornflowerblue":"#6495ed","cornsilk":"#fff8dc","crimson":"#dc143c","cyan":"#00ffff",
    "darkblue":"#00008b","darkcyan":"#008b8b","darkgoldenrod":"#b8860b","darkgray":"#a9a9a9","darkgreen":"#006400","darkkhaki":"#bdb76b","darkmagenta":"#8b008b","darkolivegreen":"#556b2f",
    "darkorange":"#ff8c00","darkorchid":"#9932cc","darkred":"#8b0000","darksalmon":"#e9967a","darkseagreen":"#8fbc8f","darkslateblue":"#483d8b","darkslategray":"#2f4f4f","darkturquoise":"#00ced1",
    "darkviolet":"#9400d3","deeppink":"#ff1493","deepskyblue":"#00bfff","dimgray":"#696969","dodgerblue":"#1e90ff",
    "firebrick":"#b22222","floralwhite":"#fffaf0","forestgreen":"#228b22","fuchsia":"#ff00ff",
    "gainsboro":"#dcdcdc","ghostwhite":"#f8f8ff","gold":"#ffd700","goldenrod":"#daa520","gray":"#808080","green":"#008000","greenyellow":"#adff2f",
    "honeydew":"#f0fff0","hotpink":"#ff69b4",
    "indianred ":"#cd5c5c","indigo":"#4b0082","ivory":"#fffff0","khaki":"#f0e68c",
    "lavender":"#e6e6fa","lavenderblush":"#fff0f5","lawngreen":"#7cfc00","lemonchiffon":"#fffacd","lightblue":"#add8e6","lightcoral":"#f08080","lightcyan":"#e0ffff","lightgoldenrodyellow":"#fafad2",
    "lightgrey":"#d3d3d3","lightgreen":"#90ee90","lightpink":"#ffb6c1","lightsalmon":"#ffa07a","lightseagreen":"#20b2aa","lightskyblue":"#87cefa","lightslategray":"#778899","lightsteelblue":"#b0c4de",
    "lightyellow":"#ffffe0","lime":"#00ff00","limegreen":"#32cd32","linen":"#faf0e6",
    "magenta":"#ff00ff","maroon":"#800000","mediumaquamarine":"#66cdaa","mediumblue":"#0000cd","mediumorchid":"#ba55d3","mediumpurple":"#9370d8","mediumseagreen":"#3cb371","mediumslateblue":"#7b68ee",
    "mediumspringgreen":"#00fa9a","mediumturquoise":"#48d1cc","mediumvioletred":"#c71585","midnightblue":"#191970","mintcream":"#f5fffa","mistyrose":"#ffe4e1","moccasin":"#ffe4b5",
    "navajowhite":"#ffdead","navy":"#000080",
    "oldlace":"#fdf5e6","olive":"#808000","olivedrab":"#6b8e23","orange":"#ffa500","orangered":"#ff4500","orchid":"#da70d6",
    "palegoldenrod":"#eee8aa","palegreen":"#98fb98","paleturquoise":"#afeeee","palevioletred":"#d87093","papayawhip":"#ffefd5","peachpuff":"#ffdab9","peru":"#cd853f","pink":"#ffc0cb","plum":"#dda0dd","powderblue":"#b0e0e6","purple":"#800080",
    "rebeccapurple":"#663399","red":"#ff0000","rosybrown":"#bc8f8f","royalblue":"#4169e1",
    "saddlebrown":"#8b4513","salmon":"#fa8072","sandybrown":"#f4a460","seagreen":"#2e8b57","seashell":"#fff5ee","sienna":"#a0522d","silver":"#c0c0c0","skyblue":"#87ceeb","slateblue":"#6a5acd","slategray":"#708090","snow":"#fffafa","springgreen":"#00ff7f","steelblue":"#4682b4",
    "tan":"#d2b48c","teal":"#008080","thistle":"#d8bfd8","tomato":"#ff6347","turquoise":"#40e0d0",
    "violet":"#ee82ee",
    "wheat":"#f5deb3","white":"#ffffff","whitesmoke":"#f5f5f5",
    "yellow":"#ffff00","yellowgreen":"#9acd32"};

    if (typeof colours[colour.toLowerCase()] != 'undefined')
        return colours[colour.toLowerCase()];

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Copy / paste / search / replace

Comment: You might want to guard against inherited properties ;) `colourNameToHex('constructor')`

Comment: Not trying to knock the wind out of anyone's answer sails here, but as I linked to in the answer I submitted, there is a way to get HEX and RGB from named colors programatically in all browsers with \out having a gigantic table like this. Do people on Stack not read below the fold generally?

Comment: For both spellings of gray, you'll also need these. The rest seem to be there based on my visual comparison. "darkgrey":"#a9a9a9", "darkslategrey":"#2f4f4f","dimgrey":"#696969","grey":"#808080","lightgray":"#d3d3d3","lightslategrey""#778899","slategrey":"#708090",

Comment: This simple solution is better than the fancy ones using getComputedStyle and canvas for one big reason: you can map additional color names to the hex values. For example, we have a clothing retailer client that likes to use marketing names for primary colors such as "Sunflower Yellow" etc. that all map back to yellow, so to convert this to color swatches we just need to add in synonyms for yellow. Once the look-up table is set, there's no maintenance needed, so not sure why some think maintenance is an issue with this solution.

Comment: A possible solution (avoiding hard-coded data) would be setting the new textual value (for example 'red' or 'DarkOliveGreen') to a (possibly invisible) element and 'color-pick' the color of the element. I'm not sure, but perhaps Javascript would do the trick.

Comment: @10basetom Not a real reason, you can easily use the above solution to map your custom names to rgb values (or css colors) and use nate 's answer to convert them to hex.

Comment: @WardD.S. I think you misunderstood me -- I upvoted this solution and began my comment with "This simple solution is better...".

Comment: And I argued that the reason you provided for saying that it's better aren't quite valid. In your use case you can use another method (like Nate's) to compute all css-known colours. To add "sunflower yellow", you can use a simple object (similar to above, indeed) to first map these uncommon names to either their css-known synonyms or an rgb value. This will look, imo, much cleaner and will be much easier maintained over time. There's no reason to include ALL colours in the object because you want to add some to the built-in list.

Comment: This answer is out of date (and imo manal creation of a huge array is not worth this many upvotes).  A far better solution (that will not need updates any time new colors are added) is [the answer from @JayB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47355187) below.

Comment: Missing "transparent", "#00FFFFFF" works

Comment: While not ideal, this solution is helpful for scenarios where JS is not necessarily being run in a browser.

Answer (score 88):

@dlauzon suggested I convert my comment into an answer. Thanks for suggesting! Here it is :)

```
function standardize_color(str){
    var ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = str;
    return ctx.fillStyle;
}
```

```js
function standardize_color(str){
    var ctx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = str;
    return ctx.fillStyle;
}

document.getElementById("myspan1").innerHTML = standardize_color("red");
document.getElementById("myspan2").innerHTML = standardize_color("PeachPuff");
document.getElementById("myspan3").innerHTML = standardize_color("PaleGoldenRod"); 
document.getElementById("myspan4").innerHTML = standardize_color("RGB(123,234,142)"); 
document.getElementById("myspan5").innerHTML = standardize_color("HSL(284,6%,49%)");
```

```css
span { font-weight:800; }
```

```html
The color named "Red" has a code of: <span id="myspan1">(requires js)</span>.<br>
 ...and color "PeachPuff"'s code is: <span id="myspan2">(requires js)</span>.<br>
 ...and "PaleGoldenRod" is: <span id="myspan3">(requires js)</span>.<br><br>
 
It works with "RGB(123,234,142)" too: <span id="myspan4">(needs js)</span>  
and therefore with: "HSL(284,6%,49%)", which is: <span id="myspan5">(requires js)
</span>.  Handy!
```

Comment: Best answer indeed. Note that passing an invalid color will give you the default fill colour (#000000)

Comment: What does it actually return?

Comment: This works for named colors, the `rgb`, `hsl` and `hwb` notations, but not for `lch`, `oklch`, `lab` or `oklab`. Does anybody know if that is intended behavior?

Comment: I sometimes get back rgba(). (Google Chrome, Windows)

Comment: It won´t work if canvas is not allowed. (librefwolf)

Answer (score 68):

This will give it to you in RGB - you should be able to do the hex conversion pretty easily.

```
d = document.createElement("div");
d.style.color = "white";
document.body.appendChild(d)
//Color in RGB 
window.getComputedStyle(d).color
```

Get Computed style is not supported on all browsers.

Comment: IE9+, all evergreen browsers as of this comment (2014/08/20) http://caniuse.com/#feat=getcomputedstyle

Comment: Note that this appends an element to your `<body>`; you should remove it after checking its color.

Comment: You do _not_ even need to append the element to your document to check its style, circumventing that problem.

Comment: On Chrome, it the node does require to be in the DOM in order to get anything from `getCompuedStyle`. Otherwise the color attribute is `""`.

Comment: Can confirm the appendChild is required on Chrome. Also note: it just inherits the color from document.body if an invalid color string is provided.

Comment: `getComputedStyle` lies, if you use this method you *must* manually verify it.

Comment: @John Can you please explain what you mean by "lies"?

Answer (score 51):

#### Edit: I've cleaned this up a bit and made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/njvack/02ad8efcb0d552b0230d) and [demo](http://bl.ocks.org/njvack/02ad8efcb0d552b0230d) of it. The basic approach remains the same.

The "add an element to the DOM and check its ComputedStyle" approach seems a little complex to me — you need to add it and check it and remember to remove it and you're changing the DOM just to compute a color and does it cause reflow? So here's a solution based on a temporary (and never rendered) `<canvas>`:

```
function colorToRGBA(color) {
    // Returns the color as an array of [r, g, b, a] -- all range from 0 - 255
    // color must be a valid canvas fillStyle. This will cover most anything
    // you'd want to use.
    // Examples:
    // colorToRGBA('red')  # [255, 0, 0, 255]
    // colorToRGBA('#f00') # [255, 0, 0, 255]
    var cvs, ctx;
    cvs = document.createElement('canvas');
    cvs.height = 1;
    cvs.width = 1;
    ctx = cvs.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 1, 1);
    return ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 1, 1).data;
}

function byteToHex(num) {
    // Turns a number (0-255) into a 2-character hex number (00-ff)
    return ('0'+num.toString(16)).slice(-2);
}

function colorToHex(color) {
    // Convert any CSS color to a hex representation
    // Examples:
    // colorToHex('red')            # '#ff0000'
    // colorToHex('rgb(255, 0, 0)') # '#ff0000'
    var rgba, hex;
    rgba = colorToRGBA(color);
    hex = [0,1,2].map(
        function(idx) { return byteToHex(rgba[idx]); }
        ).join('');
    return "#"+hex;
}
```

Note that this lets you use anything that's a valid canvas fillStyle, so if you want to gin up a 1 pixel pattern from an image, it'll tell you the color of that as well.

I've tested this in reasonably modern versions of IE, Chrome, Safari, and Firefox.

Comment: function standardize_color(str){  
        var ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');  
        ctx.fillStyle = str;  
        return ctx.fillStyle;  
    }

Comment: That's super neat! I'm not sure if I like it better or not; with the "ctx.fillStyle normalizes colors to rbga" trick you can't put a gradient or pattern in. I guess it answers the OP in fewer lines of code but it's somewhat less flexible.

Comment: It's even per-spec: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#dom-context-2d-fillstyle

Comment: Thanks! Only thing that also works with `oklch` colors for me

Comment: It won´t work if canvas was disabled. It will be disabled for users that are aware of fingerprinting.

Answer (score 28):

Here function where you use the browser to calculate it for you

```
function getHexColor(colorStr) {
    var a = document.createElement('div');
    a.style.color = colorStr;
    var colors = window.getComputedStyle( document.body.appendChild(a) ).color.match(/\d+/g).map(function(a){ return parseInt(a,10); });
    document.body.removeChild(a);
    return (colors.length >= 3) ? '#' + (((1 << 24) + (colors[0] << 16) + (colors[1] << 8) + colors[2]).toString(16).substr(1)) : false;
}
getHexColor('teal') // returns #008080
```

**Explanation by line:**

- Create html element
- Set the color
- Get the rgb-code form the element which is just appended to the body (so it is rendered), filter numbers and convert each number to an integer.
- Remove the html element we just created
- Return the HEX code using zyklus code (see credits for more info)

*credits to [zyklus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb#comment6408455_5623914) for his rgb to hex code*

Comment: one liner convert from rgb(a) to #hex
`var colors = '#'+window.getComputedStyle(document.body.appendChild(a)).color.match(/\d+/g).map(function(a,i){ return i>2 ? '' : ('0'+parseInt(a,10).toString(16)).substr(-2); }).join('');`

Answer (score 14):

Here's an all purpose solution that does exactly what you want in every browser that is 100% programmatic, goodbye giant static table of names and hex values!:

```
// Here is the solution tied together as a native String native extension using 
// MooTools, though you can implement the same thing in whatever framework you prefer:

(function(String){

var valueMatch = {
        'rgb(0,0,0)': { 'black': ' ', 'rgb(0,0,0)': ' ' },
        'rgba(0,0,0,0)': { 'transparent': ' ', 'rgba(0,0,0,0)': ' ' },
        '#ffffff': { 'transparent': ' ' },
        'transparent': { 'transparent': ' ' }
    },
    colorFromProbe = function(color){
        color = color.toString();
        if(!color.match(/^#.+$|^[^0-9]+$/)) return color;
        var probe = ($('moo_color_probe') || new Element('textarea', {
                'id': 'moo_color_probe',
                'styles': {
                    'display': 'none',
                    'color': 'transparent'
                }
            }).inject(document.body, 'after'));
        try{ probe.setStyle('color', color) } catch(e){ return color } //IE throws an error instead of defaulting the style to some color or transparent when the value is unrecognized
        var computed = (Browser.ie) ? ieColorToHex(probe) : (Browser.opera) ? probe.style.color : probe.getComputedStyle('color'),
            match = valueMatch[computed.replace(/ /g, '')];
        probe.setStyle('color', 'transparent');
        if((!Browser.ie || Browser.ie9) && color == 'transparent' && (match && match['transparent'])) return 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)';
        return (computed == 'transparent' || match && !match[color.replace(/ /g, '')]) ? color : computed;
    },
    ieColorToHex = function(probe){ // Special IE mojo, thanks to Dean Edwards for the inspiration, his code used a pop-up window to test the color, I found you can simply use a textarea instead ;)
        var value = probe.set('value', '').createTextRange().queryCommandValue("ForeColor");
        value = (((value & 0x0000ff) << 16) | (value & 0x00ff00) | ((value & 0xff0000) >>> 16)).toString(16);
        return "#000000".slice(0, 7 - value.length) + value;
    };

    String.implement({
        colorToRgb: function(){
            var color = colorFromProbe(this);
            return (color.charAt(0) == '#') ? color.hexToRgb() : color;
        },
        colorToHex: function(){
            var color = colorFromProbe(this);
            return (color.test('rgb')) ? color.rgbToHex() : color;
        }
    });

})(String);
```

A more complete explanation and live example can be found here:
http://www.backalleycoder.com/2010/10/05/converting-css-named-colors-to-rgb-and-hex/

Comment: +1 for the programmatic way. I couldn't use it though because this is an expensive way of resolving color and will not work smooth if I need to resolve a hundred values - for that case the "lame" lookup list works much better, though admittedly is pain in the ass to maintain :)

Comment: Andrey, I can guarantee you that it is not even as close to as expensive as styles animations with any of the JS frameworks. With animations you are setting multiple styles thousands of times over a given period to animate a few properties of something. This is actually not unlike that type of operation, so finding values for a few hundred colors is cake, there's no noticeable performance impact.

Comment: @csuwldcat: I'm far from convinced the hideous hack to make this work in IE is preferable to the big look-up table. There's definitely going to be a performance hit, and it makes it impossible to create a reverse look-up of colour names for RGB values, which can also be useful. +1 nonetheless, it hadn't occurred to me use a `TextRange` and `queryCommandValue()`.

Comment: @csuwldcat: In a simple test on my machine, using a look-up table to resolve the colour is between 20 and 50 times faster than doing it via the DOM, depending on the browser.

Comment: I am not surprised a hash was faster than accessing computed styles, it is of course a direct look-up on an object, so that goes without saying. The issue that this programmatic method solves that no static object, are cases of unknown color input.

I would think that the use cases for needing a color look-up wouldn't require it thousands of times in a short burst. More likely it is a user typing in a color name into a text box or something more metered.

To be fair, you could reduce nearly every attribute, param, and method return value in the DOM to a hash table, but of course we don't.

Comment: @csuwldcat: All true, and between us we've covered the issue pretty thoroughly. I think my main point is that both approaches are valid, and that which is preferable depends on the situation, whereas your comments seem to suggest you think the programmatic solution is inherently superior.

Comment: How do you use this function?
For example, to convert 'blue' to RGB?

Comment: @DouglasK.Bell the script was written using the MooTools framework's syntax - though it does not use much, so it should be easy to snap out to vanilla JS or jQuery. 

If you want to use it as is, load MooTools and all native String objects in your JS will now have the methods 'colorToRgb' and 'colorToHex'. You would literally just do 'blue'.colorToRgb(); and it would return the RGB value.

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to rely on `getComputedStyle(...)`.

**Example of using `getComputedStyle`:**

```
function convertToHexColor(englishColor) {

    // create a temporary div. 
    var div = $('<div></div>').appendTo("body").css('background-color', englishColor);
    var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(div[0]);

    // get computed color.
    var computedColor = computedStyle.backgroundColor;

    // cleanup temporary div.
    div.remove();

    // done.
    return computedColor;

    // The above returns "rgb(R, G, B)" on IE9/Chrome20/Firefox13.
};
```

**And to convert "rgb(R, G, B)" to #RRGGBB you can use:**

```
function convertRGBDecimalToHex(rgb)
{
    var regex = /rgb *\( *([0-9]{1,3}) *, *([0-9]{1,3}) *, *([0-9]{1,3}) *\)/;
    var values = regex.exec(rgb);
    if(values.length != 4)
    {
        return rgb; // fall back to what was given.              
    }
    var r = Math.round(parseFloat(values[1]));
    var g = Math.round(parseFloat(values[2]));
    var b = Math.round(parseFloat(values[3]));
    return "#" 
        + (r + 0x10000).toString(16).substring(3).toUpperCase() 
        + (g + 0x10000).toString(16).substring(3).toUpperCase()
        + (b + 0x10000).toString(16).substring(3).toUpperCase();
}
```

Comment: @pimvdb Depends on how often you need to be mapping colors. You could keep the same div always in the DOM to save some time that way -- then the rest of the time spent is on two `css` calls (one of which probably resorts to a computed style call).

Comment: I do not believe jQuery does this, I just reviewed their source and nowhere in it does it contain a section that performs the logic needed to accomplish this. Care to include a jsFiddle link showing you setting a named color using the style object setter with jQuery and then it returning the hex?

Comment: @csuwldcat Thanks for the comment. My previous code example stopped working -- I'm not sure why now it was working originally. Anyways, I have posted new code above that works, and here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GRsCr/32/.

Comment: FWIW, you don't need to convert the hex values to upper case.

Answer (score 3):

building on [Greg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1573141/731179) including gray/gray version

added: flag to pass through unresolved strings

available as [gist colorhelpersforcanvas.js](https://gist.github.com/mxfh/4719348)

```
String.prototype.colorNameToHex = function (returnUnresolved) { // color list from https://stackoverflow.com/q/1573053/731179  with added gray/gray
    var hexRGB, definedColorNames = {"aliceblue": "#f0f8ff", "antiquewhite": "#faebd7", "aqua": "#00ffff", "aquamarine": "#7fffd4", "azure": "#f0ffff", "beige": "#f5f5dc", "bisque": "#ffe4c4", "black": "#000000", "blanchedalmond": "#ffebcd", "blue": "#0000ff", "blueviolet": "#8a2be2", "brown": "#a52a2a", "burlywood": "#deb887", "cadetblue": "#5f9ea0", "chartreuse": "#7fff00", "chocolate": "#d2691e", "coral": "#ff7f50", "cornflowerblue": "#6495ed", "cornsilk": "#fff8dc", "crimson": "#dc143c", "cyan": "#00ffff", "darkblue": "#00008b", "darkcyan": "#008b8b", "darkgoldenrod": "#b8860b", "darkgray": "#a9a9a9", "darkgreen": "#006400", "darkkhaki": "#bdb76b", "darkmagenta": "#8b008b", "darkolivegreen": "#556b2f", "darkorange": "#ff8c00", "darkorchid": "#9932cc", "darkred": "#8b0000", "darksalmon": "#e9967a", "darkseagreen": "#8fbc8f", "darkslateblue": "#483d8b", "darkslategray": "#2f4f4f", "darkturquoise": "#00ced1", "darkviolet": "#9400d3", "deeppink": "#ff1493", "deepskyblue": "#00bfff", "dimgray": "#696969", "dodgerblue": "#1e90ff", "firebrick": "#b22222", "floralwhite": "#fffaf0", "forestgreen": "#228b22", "fuchsia": "#ff00ff", "gainsboro": "#dcdcdc", "ghostwhite": "#f8f8ff", "gold": "#ffd700", "goldenrod": "#daa520", "gray": "#808080", "green": "#008000", "greenyellow": "#adff2f", "honeydew": "#f0fff0", "hotpink": "#ff69b4", "indianred ": "#cd5c5c", "indigo ": "#4b0082", "ivory": "#fffff0", "khaki": "#f0e68c", "lavender": "#e6e6fa", "lavenderblush": "#fff0f5", "lawngreen": "#7cfc00", "lemonchiffon": "#fffacd", "lightblue": "#add8e6", "lightcoral": "#f08080", "lightcyan": "#e0ffff", "lightgoldenrodyellow": "#fafad2", "lightgrey": "#d3d3d3", "lightgreen": "#90ee90", "lightpink": "#ffb6c1", "lightsalmon": "#ffa07a", "lightseagreen": "#20b2aa", "lightskyblue": "#87cefa", "lightslategray": "#778899", "lightsteelblue": "#b0c4de", "lightyellow": "#ffffe0", "lime": "#00ff00", "limegreen": "#32cd32", "linen": "#faf0e6", "magenta": "#ff00ff", "maroon": "#800000", "mediumaquamarine": "#66cdaa", "mediumblue": "#0000cd", "mediumorchid": "#ba55d3", "mediumpurple": "#9370d8", "mediumseagreen": "#3cb371", "mediumslateblue": "#7b68ee", "mediumspringgreen": "#00fa9a", "mediumturquoise": "#48d1cc", "mediumvioletred": "#c71585", "midnightblue": "#191970", "mintcream": "#f5fffa", "mistyrose": "#ffe4e1", "moccasin": "#ffe4b5", "navajowhite": "#ffdead", "navy": "#000080", "oldlace": "#fdf5e6", "olive": "#808000", "olivedrab": "#6b8e23", "orange": "#ffa500", "orangered": "#ff4500", "orchid": "#da70d6", "palegoldenrod": "#eee8aa", "palegreen": "#98fb98", "paleturquoise": "#afeeee", "palevioletred": "#d87093", "papayawhip": "#ffefd5", "peachpuff": "#ffdab9", "peru": "#cd853f", "pink": "#ffc0cb", "plum": "#dda0dd", "powderblue": "#b0e0e6", "purple": "#800080", "red": "#ff0000", "rosybrown": "#bc8f8f", "royalblue": "#4169e1", "saddlebrown": "#8b4513", "salmon": "#fa8072", "sandybrown": "#f4a460", "seagreen": "#2e8b57", "seashell": "#fff5ee", "sienna": "#a0522d", "silver": "#c0c0c0", "skyblue": "#87ceeb", "slateblue": "#6a5acd", "slategray": "#708090", "snow": "#fffafa", "springgreen": "#00ff7f", "steelblue": "#4682b4", "tan": "#d2b48c", "teal": "#008080", "thistle": "#d8bfd8", "tomato": "#ff6347", "turquoise": "#40e0d0", "violet": "#ee82ee", "wheat": "#f5deb3", "white": "#ffffff", "whitesmoke": "#f5f5f5", "yellow": "#ffff00", "yellowgreen": "#9acd32", "darkgrey": "#a9a9a9", "darkslategrey": "#2f4f4f", "dimgrey": "#696969", "grey": "#808080", "lightgray": "#d3d3d3", "lightslategrey": "#778899", "slategrey": "#708090"};
    if (definedColorNames[this.toLowerCase()] !== undefined) {
        hexRGB = definedColorNames[this.toLowerCase()];
        // to keep unresolved strings set flag returnUnresolved to true
    } else {if (returnUnresolved) {hexRGB = this; } else {hexRGB = undefined; } }
    return hexRGB;
};
```

some test cases:

```
console.log("black".colorNameToHex());                //returns #000000
console.log("rgba(100,100,0,0.7)".colorNameToHex());  //returns undefined 
console.log("rgba(100,100,0,0.7)".colorNameToHex(1)); //returns rgba(100,100,0,0.7)
```

as a bonus here my use case for that in a color-string to color-string-with-alpha conversion:

works with any [css defined color](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#CSS_colors) including: rgba, rgb, r%g%b%, #rgb, #rrggbb, hsl, hsla

mostly useful in drawing with alpha/opacity/transparency onto a HTML5 canvas element with passed on color strings

```
String.prototype.setAlpha = function (alpha) {
    // change alpha of color string in any css color space
    // intended for use in canvas/svg
    // currently implemented:
    // css defined colors               > rgba
    // rgba, rgb, r%g%b%, #rgb, #rrggbb > rgba
    // hsl, hsla                        > hsla
    // unresolved                       > as is
    //
    // If no alpha is passed its is set to 1 or keeps the value in rgba/hsla

    // kill whitespace split at "(", ")", ","
    var i, hex, c = this.replace(/\s/g, '').split(/[\(\),]/);
    function extractHex(string) {
        if (string.charAt(0) === "#") {  // detect hex strings
            hex = string.replace(/#/g, '');
            string = "hex";
        } else {hex = undefined; }
        return string;
    }
    extractHex(c[0]);
    if (["rgba", "rgb", "hsla", "hsl", "hex"].indexOf(c[0]) === -1) {
        c[0] = extractHex(c[0].colorNameToHex(1)); // detect defined color names
    }
    switch (c[0]) {
    case "rgba":
        if (alpha === undefined) {alpha = c[4]; }
        c = "rgba(" + c[1] + ", " + c[2] + ", " + c[3] + ", " + alpha + ")";
        break;
    case "rgb":
        if (alpha === undefined) {alpha = 1; }
        //  if colors are in percentage values
        for  (i = 1; i <= 3; i = i + 1) {
            if (c[i].charAt(c[i].length - 1) === "%") {
                c[i] = Math.round(c[i].replace(/%/g, '') * 2.55);
            }
        }
        c = "rgba(" + c[1] + ", " + c[2] + ", " + c[3] + ", " + alpha + ")";
        break;
    case "hsl":
        if (alpha === undefined) {alpha = 1; }
        c = "hsla(" + c[1] + ", " + c[2] + ", " + c[3] + ", " + alpha + ")";
        break;
    case "hsla":
        if (alpha === undefined) {alpha = c[4]; }
        c = "hsla(" + c[1] + ", " + c[2] + ", " + c[3] + ", " + alpha + ")";
        break;
    case "hex":
        if (alpha === undefined) {alpha = 1; }
        if (hex.length === 3) {
            c[1] = parseInt(hex.charAt(0) + hex.charAt(0), 16);
            c[2] = parseInt(hex.charAt(1) + hex.charAt(1), 16);
            c[3] = parseInt(hex.charAt(2) + hex.charAt(2), 16);
        } else if (hex.length === 6) {
            c[1] = parseInt(hex.charAt(0) + hex.charAt(1), 16);
            c[2] = parseInt(hex.charAt(2) + hex.charAt(3), 16);
            c[3] = parseInt(hex.charAt(4) + hex.charAt(5), 16);
        } else {break; }
        c = "rgba(" + c[1] + ", " + c[2] + ", " + c[3] + ", " + alpha + ")";
        break;
    default: c = this; break;
    }
    return c;
};
```

test:

```
console.log("orange".setAlpha(0.3));
```

Comment: Please do not extend primitive objects because it greatly reduces performance everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Download & include the [w3color.js](https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3color.js) from [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_converter.asp).

then in your script you can use any of the following functions:

```
let c = w3color("violet");
c.darker(n)
c.desaturate(n)
c.isDark(n)
c.lighter(n)
c.saturate(n)
c.toCmyk()
c.toCmykString()
c.toCmykStringDecimal()
c.toHexString()
c.toHsl()
c.toHslString()
c.toHslStringDecimal()
c.toHslaString()
c.toHwb()
c.toHwbString()
c.toHwbStringDecimal()
c.toHwbaString()
c.toName()
c.toNcol()
c.toNcolString()
c.toNcolStringDecimal()
c.toNcolaString()
c.toRgb()
c.toRgbString()
c.toRgbaString()
```

Answer (score 2):

Run the snippet to see how easily "any" [valid CSS color](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#Syntax) (HSL, names, hex, system colors*, etc.) can be converted to R/G/B values using any element you happen to have laying around.

**Enter a value of* **`background`** *and you'll get your Windows Desktop background color (in Firefox, anyways).*

```js
go();
function go() {
  clr.style.backgroundColor = document.getElementById('txt').value;
  document.getElementById('rgb').innerHTML = window.getComputedStyle(clr).backgroundColor;
}
```

```css
* { margin:0; box-sizing:border-box; font-family:verdana; overflow:hidden; }
#txt,#rgb,#clr { height:30vh; width:97vw; padding:5vmin; margin:2vmin; font-size:13vh; border:1vmin solid; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;}
#txt{margin-bottom:0;}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='txt' onkeyup='go()' value='chartreuse' placeholder='Enter any css color . . .' autofocus>
<div id='clr'></div>
<div id='rgb'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution from [Ties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24366628/6141587) converted to TypeScript:

```
export const getHexColorFromLiteral = (
  colorStr:
    | 'aliceblue'
    | 'antiquewhite'
    | 'aqua'
    | 'aquamarine'
    | 'azure'
    | 'beige'
    | 'bisque'
    | 'black'
    | 'blanchedalmond'
    | 'blue'
    | 'blueviolet'
    | 'brown'
    | 'burlywood'
    | 'cadetblue'
    | 'chartreuse'
    | 'chocolate'
    | 'coral'
    | 'cornflowerblue'
    | 'cornsilk'
    | 'crimson'
    | 'cyan'
    | 'darkblue'
    | 'darkcyan'
    | 'darkgoldenrod'
    | 'darkgray'
    | 'darkgreen'
    | 'darkkhaki'
    | 'darkmagenta'
    | 'darkolivegreen'
    | 'darkorange'
    | 'darkorchid'
    | 'darkred'
    | 'darksalmon'
    | 'darkseagreen'
    | 'darkslateblue'
    | 'darkslategray'
    | 'darkturquoise'
    | 'darkviolet'
    | 'deeppink'
    | 'deepskyblue'
    | 'dimgray'
    | 'dodgerblue'
    | 'firebrick'
    | 'floralwhite'
    | 'forestgreen'
    | 'fuchsia'
    | 'gainsboro'
    | 'ghostwhite'
    | 'gold'
    | 'goldenrod'
    | 'gray'
    | 'green'
    | 'greenyellow'
    | 'honeydew'
    | 'hotpink'
    | 'indianred'
    | 'indigo'
    | 'ivory'
    | 'khaki'
    | 'lavender'
    | 'lavenderblush'
    | 'lawngreen'
    | 'lemonchiffon'
    | 'lightblue'
    | 'lightcoral'
    | 'lightcyan'
    | 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
    | 'lightgray'
    | 'lightgreen'
    | 'lightpink'
    | 'lightsalmon'
    | 'lightseagreen'
    | 'lightskyblue'
    | 'lightslategray'
    | 'lightsteelblue'
    | 'lightyellow'
    | 'lime'
    | 'limegreen'
    | 'linen'
    | 'magenta'
    | 'maroon'
    | 'mediumaquamarine'
    | 'mediumblue'
    | 'mediumorchid'
    | 'mediumpurple'
    | 'mediumseagreen'
    | 'mediumslateblue'
    | 'mediumspringgreen'
    | 'mediumturquoise'
    | 'mediumvioletred'
    | 'midnightblue'
    | 'mintcream'
    | 'mistyrose'
    | 'moccasin'
    | 'navajowhite'
    | 'navy'
    | 'oldlace'
    | 'olive'
    | 'olivedrab'
    | 'orange'
    | 'orangered'
    | 'orchid'
    | 'palegoldenrod'
    | 'palegreen'
    | 'paleturquoise'
    | 'palevioletred'
    | 'papayawhip'
    | 'peachpuff'
    | 'peru'
    | 'pink'
    | 'plum'
    | 'powderblue'
    | 'purple'
    | 'rebeccapurple'
    | 'red'
    | 'rosybrown'
    | 'royalblue'
    | 'saddlebrown'
    | 'salmon'
    | 'sandybrown'
    | 'seagreen'
    | 'seashell'
    | 'sienna'
    | 'silver'
    | 'skyblue'
    | 'slateblue'
    | 'slategray'
    | 'snow'
    | 'springgreen'
    | 'steelblue'
    | 'tan'
    | 'teal'
    | 'thistle'
    | 'tomato'
    | 'turquoise'
    | 'violet'
    | 'wheat'
    | 'white'
    | 'whitesmoke'
    | 'yellow'
    | 'yellowgreen'
) => {
    const div = document.createElement('div')
    div.style.color = colorStr
    document.body.appendChild(div)

    const computedColor = window.getComputedStyle(div).color
    const matchResult = computedColor.match(/\d+/g)
    if (matchResult !== null) {
        const colors = matchResult.map((a) => parseInt(a, 10))

        document.body.removeChild(div)
        return colors.length >= 3
            ? '#' + ((1 << 24) + (colors[0] << 16) + (colors[1] << 8) + colors[2]).toString(16).substr(1)
            : false
    }

    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not that's built-in, as far as I know.  It would be kind of a hack, but I think you could create an invisible div, set its CSS background property to the named color, then use JS to get the background color of the div, then delete the div.

Comment: Where is the guarantee that computed color value will be represented as hex?

Comment: @kangax: JS would give you the color.  how you want to represent it is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

[IE8 getComputedStyle polyfill](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aight/1.1.1/aight.min.js) if needed

```
var rgbToHex = function(r, g, b) {
    return "#" + (16777216 | b | (g << 8) | (r << 16)).toString(16).slice(1);
};

var d = document.createElement('div');
d.style.color = 'white';
window.document.body.appendChild(d);
var parts = (window.getComputedStyle(d).color || '').match(/\d+/g);
var f = function(n) { return parseInt(n, 10); };
window.document.body.removeChild(d);
var hex = rgbToHex(f(parts[0]), f(parts[1]), f(parts[2]));

//"#ffffff"
```

Answer (score 0):

This function request a named color and send return a hexadecimal color value.
If the named color not supported (example "whyte") send back black color by default but on consol you can find a warning:
Not supported named color: ${namedColor}

```
const namedColorToHex = namedColor => {
    const html = document.querySelector("html");
    const originalColor = html.style.color;
    html.style.color = namedColor;
    const rgbFormatBgColor = window.getComputedStyle(html).color;
    if (namedColor !== "black" && rgbFormatBgColor === "rgb(0, 0, 0)") {
        console.warn(`Not supported named color: ${namedColor}`);
    }
    html.style.color = originalColor;
    const regEx = /(\d+)/g;
    const result = rgbFormatBgColor.match(regEx);
    let hexColor = `#`;
    result.forEach(value => {
        let hex = Number(value).toString(16);
        if (hex.length === 1) {
            hex = `0${hex}`;
        }
        hexColor += hex;
    });
    return hexColor;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

With Firefox 94 you get the rgb color when formated with a color name. But you have to inject the dummy element at first to the page.

```js
// Vanilla and jQuery

console.clear();

var 
  colors = ['cyan', 'magenta', 'yellow']
  dummy     = {},
  colorObj  = {},
  rgbString = '',
  rgb2hex   = function(rgb) {
    rgb = rgb.match(/^rgba?[\s+]?\([\s+]?(\d+)[\s+]?,[\s+]?(\d+)[\s+]?,[\s+]?(\d+)[\s+]?/i);
    return (rgb && rgb.length === 4) ? "#" +
    ("0" + parseInt(rgb[1],10).toString(16)).slice(-2) +
    ("0" + parseInt(rgb[2],10).toString(16)).slice(-2) +
    ("0" + parseInt(rgb[3],10).toString(16)).slice(-2) : '';
  }
;

$(colors).each(function(i, color) {
  dummy = $('<b style="background-color:' + color + '"></b>');
  // inject the dummy
  $('body').append(dummy);
  // get the rgb color 
  rgbString = dummy.css('background-color');
  // build an object with 'color name', 'rgb color' and 'hex color'
  colorObj[i] = [color, rgbString, rgb2hex(rgbString)]; 
  // delete the dummy 
  dummy.remove();  
});

console.dir(colorObj);
```

If you need an array with all 140 color names

```js
colors = [
  'aliceblue',
  'antiquewhite',
  'aqua',
  'aquamarine',
  'azure',
  'beige',
  'bisque',
  'black',
  'blanchedalmond',
  'blue',
  'blueviolet',
  'brown',
  'burlywood',
  'cadetblue',
  'chartreuse',
  'chocolate',
  'coral',
  'cornflowerblue',
  'cornsilk',
  'crimson',
  'cyan',
  'darkblue',
  'darkcyan',
  'darkgoldenrod',
  'darkgray',
  'darkgreen',
  'darkkhaki',
  'darkmagenta',
  'darkolivegreen',
  'darkorange',
  'darkorchid',
  'darkred',
  'darksalmon',
  'darkseagreen',
  'darkslateblue',
  'darkslategray',
  'darkturquoise',
  'darkviolet',
  'deeppink',
  'deepskyblue',
  'dimgray',
  'dodgerblue',
  'firebrick',
  'floralwhite',
  'forestgreen',
  'fuchsia',
  'gainsboro',
  'ghostwhite',
  'gold',
  'goldenrod',
  'gray',
  'green',
  'greenyellow',
  'honeydew',
  'hotpink',
  'indianred',
  'indigo',
  'ivory',
  'khaki',
  'lavender',
  'lavenderblush',
  'lawngreen',
  'lemonchiffon',
  'lightblue',
  'lightcoral',
  'lightcyan',
  'lightgoldenrodyellow',
  'lightgray',
  'lightgreen',
  'lightpink',
  'lightsalmon',
  'lightseagreen',
  'lightskyblue',
  'lightslategray',
  'lightsteelblue',
  'lightyellow',
  'lime',
  'limegreen',
  'linen',
  'magenta',
  'maroon',
  'mediumaquamarine',
  'mediumblue',
  'mediumorchid',
  'mediumpurple',
  'mediumseagreen',
  'mediumslateblue',
  'mediumspringgreen',
  'mediumturquoise',
  'mediumvioletred',
  'midnightblue',
  'mintcream',
  'mistyrose',
  'moccasin',
  'navajowhite',
  'navy',
  'oldlace',
  'olive',
  'olivedrab',
  'orange',
  'orangered',
  'orchid',
  'palegoldenrod',
  'palegreen',
  'paleturquoise',
  'palevioletred',
  'papayawhip',
  'peachpuff',
  'peru',
  'pink',
  'plum',
  'powderblue',
  'purple',
  'red',
  'rosybrown',
  'royalblue',
  'saddlebrown',
  'salmon',
  'sandybrown',
  'seagreen',
  'seashell',
  'sienna',
  'silver',
  'skyblue',
  'slateblue',
  'slategray',
  'snow',
  'springgreen',
  'steelblue',
  'tan',
  'teal',
  'thistle',
  'tomato',
  'turquoise',
  'violet',
  'wheat',
  'white',
  'whitesmoke',
  'yellow',
  'yellowgreen'
]
```

Answer (score -3):

Quick code for HEX / RGB values only, might be useful to someone, and can be adapted to include names: pull the whole object in the for loop, check the name and if it matches you've got your hex / rbg.
They are taken from here:
http://www.colourlovers.com/web/blog/2008/04/22/all-120-crayon-names-color-codes-and-fun-facts

Most importantly, please notice the correct spelling of "colour" :P

```
/*COLOURS*/
function loadColourPalette() {

$("#colourPalette").empty();
//load them animated
for (var t = 0; t<120; t++){
    var c = returnColourForIndex(t);
    console.log("c is " + c);
    var div = '<div class="colourBox" id="cb'+t+'" style="background:'+c+'"></div>';
    $("#colourPalette").append(div);
}

}



function returnColourForIndex(i){

var colours = [     {hex:"CD4A4A",rgb:"205,74,74"},
                    {hex:"CC6666",rgb:"204,102,102"},
                    {hex:"BC5D58",rgb:"188,93,88"},
                    {hex:"FF5349",rgb:"255,83,73"},
                    {hex:"FD5E53",rgb:"253,94,83"},
                    {hex:"FD7C6E",rgb:"253,124,110"},
                    {hex:"FDBCB4",rgb:"253,188,180"},
                    {hex:"FF6E4A",rgb:"255,110,74"},
                    {hex:"FFA089",rgb:"255,160,137"},
                    {hex:"EA7E5D",rgb:"234,126,93"},
                    {hex:"B4674D",rgb:"180,103,77"},
                    {hex:"A5694F",rgb:"165,105,79"},
                    {hex:"FF7538",rgb:"255,117,56"},
                    {hex:"FF7F49",rgb:"255,127,73"},
                    {hex:"DD9475",rgb:"221,148,117"},
                    {hex:"FF8243",rgb:"255,130,67"},
                    {hex:"FFA474",rgb:"255,164,116"},
                    {hex:"9F8170",rgb:"159,129,112"},
                    {hex:"CD9575",rgb:"205,149,117"},
                    {hex:"EFCDB8",rgb:"239,205,184"},
                    {hex:"D68A59",rgb:"214,138,89"},
                    {hex:"DEAA88",rgb:"222,170,136"},
                    {hex:"FAA76C",rgb:"250,167,108"},
                    {hex:"FFCFAB",rgb:"255,207,171"},
                    {hex:"FFBD88",rgb:"255,189,136"},
                    {hex:"FDD9B5",rgb:"253,217,181"},
                    {hex:"FFA343",rgb:"255,163,67"},
                    {hex:"EFDBC5",rgb:"239,219,197"},
                    {hex:"FFB653",rgb:"255,182,83"},
                    {hex:"E7C697",rgb:"231,198,151"},
                    {hex:"8A795D",rgb:"138,121,93"},
                    {hex:"FAE7B5",rgb:"250,231,181"},
                    {hex:"FFCF48",rgb:"255,207,72"},
                    {hex:"FCD975",rgb:"252,217,117"},
                    {hex:"FDDB6D",rgb:"253,219,109"},
                    {hex:"FCE883",rgb:"252,232,131"},
                    {hex:"F0E891",rgb:"240,232,145"},
                    {hex:"ECEABE",rgb:"236,234,190"},
                    {hex:"BAB86C",rgb:"186,184,108"},
                    {hex:"FDFC74",rgb:"253,252,116"},
                    {hex:"FFFF99",rgb:"255,255,153"},
                    {hex:"C5E384",rgb:"197,227,132"},
                    {hex:"B2EC5D",rgb:"178,236,93"},
                    {hex:"87A96B",rgb:"135,169,107"},
                    {hex:"A8E4A0",rgb:"168,228,160"},
                    {hex:"1DF914",rgb:"29,249,20"},
                    {hex:"76FF7A",rgb:"118,255,122"},
                    {hex:"71BC78",rgb:"113,188,120"},
                    {hex:"6DAE81",rgb:"109,174,129"},
                    {hex:"9FE2BF",rgb:"159,226,191"},
                    {hex:"1CAC78",rgb:"28,172,120"},
                    {hex:"30BA8F",rgb:"48,186,143"},
                    {hex:"45CEA2",rgb:"69,206,162"},
                    {hex:"3BB08F",rgb:"59,176,143"},
                    {hex:"1CD3A2",rgb:"28,211,162"},
                    {hex:"17806D",rgb:"23,128,109"},
                    {hex:"158078",rgb:"21,128,120"},
                    {hex:"1FCECB",rgb:"31,206,203"},
                    {hex:"78DBE2",rgb:"120,219,226"},
                    {hex:"77DDE7",rgb:"119,221,231"},
                    {hex:"80DAEB",rgb:"128,218,235"},
                    {hex:"199EBD",rgb:"251,58,189"},
                    {hex:"1CA9C9",rgb:"28,169,201"},
                    {hex:"1DACD6",rgb:"291,72,214"},
                    {hex:"9ACEEB",rgb:"154,206,235"},
                    {hex:"1A4876",rgb:"26,72,118"},
                    {hex:"1974D2",rgb:"25,116,210"},
                    {hex:"2B6CC4",rgb:"43,108,196"},
                    {hex:"1F75FE",rgb:"31,117,254"},
                    {hex:"C5D0E6",rgb:"197,208,230"},
                    {hex:"B0B7C6",rgb:"176,183,198"},
                    {hex:"5D76CB",rgb:"93,118,203"},
                    {hex:"A2ADD0",rgb:"162,173,208"},
                    {hex:"979AAA",rgb:"151,154,170"},
                    {hex:"ADADD6",rgb:"173,173,214"},
                    {hex:"7366BD",rgb:"115,102,189"},
                    {hex:"7442C8",rgb:"116,66,200"},
                    {hex:"7851A9",rgb:"120,81,169"},
                    {hex:"9D81BA",rgb:"157,129,186"},
                    {hex:"926EAE",rgb:"146,110,174"},
                    {hex:"CDA4DE",rgb:"205,164,222"},
                    {hex:"8F509D",rgb:"143,80,157"},
                    {hex:"C364C5",rgb:"195,100,197"},
                    {hex:"FB7EFD",rgb:"251,126,253"},
                    {hex:"FC74FD",rgb:"252,116,253"},
                    {hex:"8E4585",rgb:"142,69,133"},
                    {hex:"FF1DCE",rgb:"255,29,206"},
                    {hex:"FF48D0",rgb:"255,72,208"},
                    {hex:"E6A8D7",rgb:"230,168,215"},
                    {hex:"C0448F",rgb:"192,68,143"},
                    {hex:"6E5160",rgb:"110,81,96"},
                    {hex:"DD4492",rgb:"221,68,146"},
                    {hex:"FF43A4",rgb:"255,67,164"},
                    {hex:"F664AF",rgb:"246,100,175"},
                    {hex:"FCB4D5",rgb:"252,180,213"},
                    {hex:"FFBCD9",rgb:"255,188,217"},
                    {hex:"F75394",rgb:"247,83,148"},
                    {hex:"FFAACC",rgb:"255,170,204"},
                    {hex:"E3256B",rgb:"227,37,107"},
                    {hex:"FDD7E4",rgb:"253,215,228"},
                    {hex:"CA3767",rgb:"202,55,103"},
                    {hex:"DE5D83",rgb:"222,93,131"},
                    {hex:"FC89AC",rgb:"252,137,172"},
                    {hex:"F780A1",rgb:"247,128,161"},
                    {hex:"C8385A",rgb:"200,56,90"},
                    {hex:"EE204D",rgb:"238,32,77"},
                    {hex:"FF496C",rgb:"255,73,108"},
                    {hex:"EF98AA",rgb:"239,152,170"},
                    {hex:"FC6C85",rgb:"252,108,133"},
                    {hex:"FC2847",rgb:"252,40,71"},
                    {hex:"FF9BAA",rgb:"255,155,170"},
                    {hex:"CB4154",rgb:"203,65,84"},
                    {hex:"FFFFFF",rgb:"255,255,255"},
                    {hex:"EDEDED",rgb:"237,237,237"},
                    {hex:"DBD7D2",rgb:"219,215,210"},
                    {hex:"CDC5C2",rgb:"205,197,194"},
                    {hex:"95918C",rgb:"149,145,140"},
                    {hex:"414A4C",rgb:"65,74,76"},
                    {hex:"232323",rgb:"35,35,35"},
                    {hex:"000000",rgb:"0,0,0"}];

return "#"+colours[i].hex;

}
```

Comment: Colour v.s. color depends on British v.s. English spelling. Therefore, color is just as right as colour as it depends on which country you are in. Also, I don't see the purpose of this at all. Why not `function hexToRGB(hex){return hex.split(/(?=(?:..)*$)/g).map(function(x){return parseInt(x,16)}).join(",")}`