# Is it possible to determine the hex value of a named color?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, colors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript function to convert color names to hex codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573053/javascript-function-to-convert-color-names-to-hex-codes)

Is it possible to retrieve or calculate the hex value that the browser is currently using for a named color? For instance I would like to be able to do something like the following:

*(Html)*:

```
<div id="container" style="background-color: lightgreen"></div>
```

*(JavaScript)*:

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var colorAsHex = getHexColor(container, "background-color");
```

At best I'm hoping for a jQuery solution that I just happen to be missing. At worst I'm fine with browser-specific hacks as long as I can cover the 4 major browsers.

Comment: Thanks. Linked issue seems applicable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('div').css('background-color')` seems to be working ... see this example [link](http://jsfiddle.net/KnW4X/)

Comment: Wow, interesting. It looks like (from just a brief test) that in jQuery 1.4.2 it returns "green", but in jQuery 1.4.4+ it returns the RGB components.

Answer (score 1):

```
var namedColor = "lightgreen";
var rgbColor = $("<div></div>").css("background-color", namedColor).css("background-color");
var match = rgbColor.match(/(\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)/);
var value = 
    (+match[1] << 16) + 
    (+match[2] << 8) + 
    (+match[3] << 0);
var hexColor = value.toString(16);
while (hexColor.length < 6) {
    hexColor = "0" + hexColor;
}
console.log("#" + hexColor)
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/XAWJK/) and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/XAWJK/show/).