# Convert RGB to ColorName String Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to find out if a DOM Element has a style which is for example a color:Red.
If this is defined on the inline style just like

```
<input type="text" style="color:Red">
```

I can get it easily with JavaScript

But how about if it's defined on a role -  I mean as a css class and assign the class to the DOM Element

With javascript I know I can get the color with some method call computedStyle and give it the name of the property but it brings me the color in RGB numbers mode in Firefox and in IE it gets the color name

my question here is how to convert RGB into a simple color name?

Comment: I would say that there's nothing to do this automatically since it has no apparent use. Using RGB should work all the times. Even if you need to compare it.

Comment: @tiagoboldt "No apparent use", that seems short sighted.... I am developing a tool to help designers pick colors, and while the backend uses rgba() it's helpful to show users `red` in addition to `rgb(255,0,0)` and the other ways of defining the given color. Especially if they input a named color as their primary color, they'd likely expect to see their named color spit back to them in the final color palette.

Answer (score 11):

Here is the library that will do it: Name That Color - http://chir.ag/projects/name-that-color/

Answer (score 4):

There's a sample function you could call in this answer:

[Javascript function to convert color names to hex codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573053/javascript-function-to-convert-color-names-to-hex-codes)

It does a conversion from the name to the hex value.

Comment: This is the wrong direction -- OP wants from hex code to color name, this answer is for from color name to hex code.

Answer (score 2):

I think that these are the names supported in most browsers, you could store them in a dictionary and look them up: http://www.febooti.com/products/iezoom/online-help/html-color-names-x11-color-chart.html

The x11 color names are a superset of the ones defined in css.

Comment: 2020-05-05 Link is broken

Answer (score 2):

A color name to RGB converter look up table will help, start here: http://web.njit.edu/~walsh/rgb.html.
On the other hand someone might have build it before, so try to google it: https://encrypted.google.com/search?num=100&q=SlateGray1+SlateGray2+inurl%3A.js

Answer (score 2):

Check out the https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3color.js conversion script, copied below as of 2023-04-27. It is very comprehensive, converting between named colors, hex, hsl, hwb, cmyk, and ncol  It does not, however, support colors with alpha

An easy web interface is also provided at
https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_converter.asp

```js
/* w3color.js ver.1.18 by w3schools.com (Do not remove this line)*/
(function () {
function w3color(color, elmnt) {
  if (!(this instanceof w3color)) { return new w3color(color, elmnt); }
  if (typeof color == "object") {return color; }
  this.attachValues(toColorObject(color));
  if (elmnt) {elmnt.style.backgroundColor = this.toRgbString();}
}
w3color.prototype = {
  toRgbString : function () {
    return "rgb(" + this.red + ", " + this.green + ", " + this.blue + ")";
  },
  toRgbaString : function () {
    return "rgba(" + this.red + ", " + this.green + ", " + this.blue + ", " + this.opacity + ")";
  },
  toHwbString : function () {
    return "hwb(" + this.hue + ", " + Math.round(this.whiteness * 100) + "%, " + Math.round(this.blackness * 100) + "%)";
  },
  toHwbStringDecimal : function () {
    return "hwb(" + this.hue + ", " + this.whiteness + ", " + this.blackness + ")";
  },
  toHwbaString : function () {
    return "hwba(" + this.hue + ", " + Math.round(this.whiteness * 100) + "%, " + Math.round(this.blackness * 100) + "%, " + this.opacity + ")";
  },
  toHslString : function () {
    return "hsl(" + this.hue + ", " + Math.round(this.sat * 100) + "%, " + Math.round(this.lightness * 100) + "%)";
  },
  toHslStringDecimal : function () {
    return "hsl(" + this.hue + ", " + this.sat + ", " + this.lightness + ")";
  },
  toHslaString : function () {
    return "hsla(" + this.hue + ", " + Math.round(this.sat * 100) + "%, " + Math.round(this.lightness * 100) + "%, " + this.opacity + ")";
  },
  toCmykString : function () {
    return "cmyk(" + Math.round(this.cyan * 100) + "%, " + Math.round(this.magenta * 100) + "%, " + Math.round(this.yellow * 100) + "%, " + Math.round(this.black * 100) + "%)";
  },
  toCmykStringDecimal : function () {
    return "cmyk(" + this.cyan + ", " + this.magenta + ", " + this.yellow + ", " + this.black + ")";
  },
  toNcolString : function () {
    return this.ncol + ", " + Math.round(this.whiteness * 100) + "%, " + Math.round(this.blackness * 100) + "%";
  },
  toNcolStringDecimal : function () {
    return this.ncol + ", " + this.whiteness + ", " + this.blackness;
  },
  toNcolaString : function () {
    return this.ncol + ", " + Math.round(this.whiteness * 100) + "%, " + Math.round(this.blackness * 100) + "%, " + this.opacity;
  },
  toName : function () {
    var r, g, b, colorhexs = getColorArr('hexs');
    for (i = 0; i < colorhexs.length; i++) {
      r = parseInt(colorhexs[i].substr(0,2), 16);
      g = parseInt(colorhexs[i].substr(2,2), 16);
      b = parseInt(colorhexs[i].substr(4,2), 16);
      if (this.red == r && this.green == g && this.blue == b) {
        return getColorArr('names')[i];
      }
    }
    return "";
  },
  toHexString : function () {
    var r = toHex(this.red);
    var g = toHex(this.green);
    var b = toHex(this.blue);
    return "#" +  r + g + b;
  },
  toRgb : function () {
    return {r : this.red, g : this.green, b : this.blue, a : this.opacity};
  },
  toHsl : function () {
    return {h : this.hue, s : this.sat, l : this.lightness, a : this.opacity};
  },
  toHwb : function () {
    return {h : this.hue, w : this.whiteness, b : this.blackness, a : this.opacity};
  },
  toCmyk : function () {
    return {c : this.cyan, m : this.magenta, y : this.yellow, k : this.black, a : this.opacity};
  },
  toNcol : function () {
    return {ncol : this.ncol, w : this.whiteness, b : this.blackness, a : this.opacity};
  },
  isDark : function (n) {
    var m = (n || 128);
    return (((this.red * 299 + this.green * 587 + this.blue * 114) / 1000) < m);
  },
  saturate : function (n) {
    var x, rgb, color;
    x = (n / 100 || 0.1);
    this.sat += x;
    if (this.sat > 1) {this.sat = 1;}
    rgb = hslToRgb(this.hue, this.sat, this.lightness);
    color = colorObject(rgb, this.opacity, this.hue, this.sat);
    this.attachValues(color);
  },
  desaturate : function (n) {
    var x, rgb, color;
    x = (n / 100 || 0.1);
    this.sat -= x;
    if (this.sat < 0) {this.sat = 0;}
    rgb = hslToRgb(this.hue, this.sat, this.lightness);
    color = colorObject(rgb, this.opacity, this.hue, this.sat);
    this.attachValues(color);
  },
  lighter : function (n) {
    var x, rgb, color;
    x = (n / 100 || 0.1);
    this.lightness += x;
    if (this.lightness > 1) {this.lightness = 1;}
    rgb = hslToRgb(this.hue, this.sat, this.lightness);
    color = colorObject(rgb, this.opacity, this.hue, this.sat);
    this.attachValues(color);
  },
  darker : function (n) {
    var x, rgb, color;
    x = (n / 100 || 0.1);
    this.lightness -= x;
    if (this.lightness < 0) {this.lightness = 0;}
    rgb = hslToRgb(this.hue, this.sat, this.lightness);
    color = colorObject(rgb, this.opacity, this.hue, this.sat);
    this.attachValues(color);
  },
  attachValues : function(color) {
    this.red = color.red;
    this.green = color.green;
    this.blue = color.blue;
    this.hue = color.hue;
    this.sat = color.sat;
    this.lightness = color.lightness;
    this.whiteness = color.whiteness;
    this.blackness = color.blackness;
    this.cyan = color.cyan;
    this.magenta = color.magenta;
    this.yellow = color.yellow;
    this.black = color.black;
    this.ncol = color.ncol;
    this.opacity = color.opacity;
    this.valid = color.valid;
  }
};
function toColorObject(c) {
  var x, y, typ, arr = [], arrlength, i, opacity, match, a, hue, sat, rgb, colornames = [], colorhexs = [];
  c = w3trim(c.toLowerCase());
  x = c.substr(0,1).toUpperCase();
  y = c.substr(1);
  a = 1;
  if ((x == "R" || x == "Y" || x == "G" || x == "C" || x == "B" || x == "M" || x == "W") && !isNaN(y)) {
    if (c.length == 6 && c.indexOf(",") == -1) {
    } else {
      c = "ncol(" + c + ")";
    }
  }
  if (c.length != 3 && c.length != 6 && !isNaN(c)) {c = "ncol(" + c + ")";}
  if (c.indexOf(",") > 0 && c.indexOf("(") == -1) {c = "ncol(" + c + ")";}  
  if (c.substr(0, 3) == "rgb" || c.substr(0, 3) == "hsl" || c.substr(0, 3) == "hwb" || c.substr(0, 4) == "ncol" || c.substr(0, 4) == "cmyk") {
    if (c.substr(0, 4) == "ncol") {
      if (c.split(",").length == 4 && c.indexOf("ncola") == -1) {
        c = c.replace("ncol", "ncola");
      }
      typ = "ncol";
      c = c.substr(4);
    } else if (c.substr(0, 4) == "cmyk") {
      typ = "cmyk";
      c = c.substr(4);
    } else {
      typ = c.substr(0, 3);
      c = c.substr(3);
    }
    arrlength = 3;
    opacity = false;
    if (c.substr(0, 1).toLowerCase() == "a") {
      arrlength = 4;
      opacity = true;
      c = c.substr(1);
    } else if (typ == "cmyk") {
      arrlength = 4;
      if (c.split(",").length == 5) {
        arrlength = 5;
        opacity = true;
      }
    }
    c = c.replace("(", "");
    c = c.replace(")", "");
    arr = c.split(",");
    if (typ == "rgb") {
      if (arr.length != arrlength) {
        return emptyObject();
      }
      for (i = 0; i < arrlength; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == "" || arr[i] == " ") {arr[i] = "0"; }
        if (arr[i].indexOf("%") > -1) {
          arr[i] = arr[i].replace("%", "");
          arr[i] = Number(arr[i] / 100);
          if (i < 3 ) {arr[i] = Math.round(arr[i] * 255);}
        }
        if (isNaN(arr[i])) {return emptyObject(); }
        if (parseInt(arr[i]) > 255) {arr[i] = 255; }
        if (i < 3) {arr[i] = parseInt(arr[i]);}
        if (i == 3 && Number(arr[i]) > 1) {arr[i] = 1;}
      }
      rgb = {r : arr[0], g : arr[1], b : arr[2]};
      if (opacity == true) {a = Number(arr[3]);}
    }
    if (typ == "hsl" || typ == "hwb" || typ == "ncol") {
      while (arr.length < arrlength) {arr.push("0"); }
      if (typ == "hsl" || typ == "hwb") {
        if (parseInt(arr[0]) >= 360) {arr[0] = 0; }
      }
      for (i = 1; i < arrlength; i++) {
        if (arr[i].indexOf("%") > -1) {
          arr[i] = arr[i].replace("%", "");
          arr[i] = Number(arr[i]);
          if (isNaN(arr[i])) {return emptyObject(); }
          arr[i] = arr[i] / 100;
        } else {
          arr[i] = Number(arr[i]);
        }
        if (Number(arr[i]) > 1) {arr[i] = 1;}
        if (Number(arr[i]) < 0) {arr[i] = 0;}
      }
      if (typ == "hsl") {rgb = hslToRgb(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]); hue = Number(arr[0]); sat = Number(arr[1]);}
      if (typ == "hwb") {rgb = hwbToRgb(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]);}
      if (typ == "ncol") {rgb = ncolToRgb(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]);}
      if (opacity == true) {a = Number(arr[3]);}
    }
    if (typ == "cmyk") {
      while (arr.length < arrlength) {arr.push("0"); }
      for (i = 0; i < arrlength; i++) {
        if (arr[i].indexOf("%") > -1) {
          arr[i] = arr[i].replace("%", "");
          arr[i] = Number(arr[i]);
          if (isNaN(arr[i])) {return emptyObject(); }
          arr[i] = arr[i] / 100;
        } else {
          arr[i] = Number(arr[i]);
        }
        if (Number(arr[i]) > 1) {arr[i] = 1;}
        if (Number(arr[i]) < 0) {arr[i] = 0;}
      }
      rgb = cmykToRgb(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3]);
      if (opacity == true) {a = Number(arr[4]);}
    }
  } else if (c.substr(0, 3) == "ncs") {
    rgb = ncsToRgb(c);
  } else {
    match = false;
    colornames = getColorArr('names');
    for (i = 0; i < colornames.length; i++) {
      if (c.toLowerCase() == colornames[i].toLowerCase()) {
        colorhexs = getColorArr('hexs');
        match = true;
        rgb = {
          r : parseInt(colorhexs[i].substr(0,2), 16),
          g : parseInt(colorhexs[i].substr(2,2), 16),
          b : parseInt(colorhexs[i].substr(4,2), 16)
        };
        break;
      }
    }
    if (match == false) {
      c = c.replace("#", "");
      if (c.length == 3) {c = c.substr(0,1) + c.substr(0,1) + c.substr(1,1) + c.substr(1,1) + c.substr(2,1) + c.substr(2,1);}
      for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        if (!isHex(c.substr(i, 1))) {return emptyObject(); }
      }
      arr[0] = parseInt(c.substr(0,2), 16);
      arr[1] = parseInt(c.substr(2,2), 16);
      arr[2] = parseInt(c.substr(4,2), 16);
      for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (isNaN(arr[i])) {return emptyObject(); }
      }
      rgb = {
        r : arr[0],
        g : arr[1],
        b : arr[2]
      };
    }
  }
  return colorObject(rgb, a, hue, sat);
}
function colorObject(rgb, a, h, s) {
  var hsl, hwb, cmyk, ncol, color, hue, sat;
  if (!rgb) {return emptyObject();}
  if (a === null) {a = 1;}
  hsl = rgbToHsl(rgb.r, rgb.g, rgb.b);
  hwb = rgbToHwb(rgb.r, rgb.g, rgb.b);
  cmyk = rgbToCmyk(rgb.r, rgb.g, rgb.b);
  hue = (h || hsl.h);
  sat = (s || hsl.s);   
  ncol = hueToNcol(hue);
  color = {
    red : rgb.r,
    green : rgb.g,
    blue : rgb.b,
    hue : hue,
    sat : sat,
    lightness : hsl.l,
    whiteness : hwb.w,
    blackness : hwb.b,
    cyan : cmyk.c,
    magenta : cmyk.m,
    yellow : cmyk.y,
    black : cmyk.k,
    ncol : ncol,
    opacity : a,
    valid : true
  };
  color = roundDecimals(color);
  return color;
}
function emptyObject() {
  return {
    red : 0,
    green : 0,
    blue : 0,
    hue : 0,
    sat : 0,
    lightness : 0,
    whiteness : 0,
    blackness : 0,
    cyan : 0,
    magenta : 0,
    yellow : 0,
    black : 0,
    ncol : "R",
    opacity : 1,
    valid : false
  };
}
function getColorArr(x) {
  if (x == "names") {return ['AliceBlue','AntiqueWhite','Aqua','Aquamarine','Azure','Beige','Bisque','Black','BlanchedAlmond','Blue','BlueViolet','Brown','BurlyWood','CadetBlue','Chartreuse','Chocolate','Coral','CornflowerBlue','Cornsilk','Crimson','Cyan','DarkBlue','DarkCyan','DarkGoldenRod','DarkGray','DarkGrey','DarkGreen','DarkKhaki','DarkMagenta','DarkOliveGreen','DarkOrange','DarkOrchid','DarkRed','DarkSalmon','DarkSeaGreen','DarkSlateBlue','DarkSlateGray','DarkSlateGrey','DarkTurquoise','DarkViolet','DeepPink','DeepSkyBlue','DimGray','DimGrey','DodgerBlue','FireBrick','FloralWhite','ForestGreen','Fuchsia','Gainsboro','GhostWhite','Gold','GoldenRod','Gray','Grey','Green','GreenYellow','HoneyDew','HotPink','IndianRed','Indigo','Ivory','Khaki','Lavender','LavenderBlush','LawnGreen','LemonChiffon','LightBlue','LightCoral','LightCyan','LightGoldenRodYellow','LightGray','LightGrey','LightGreen','LightPink','LightSalmon','LightSeaGreen','LightSkyBlue','LightSlateGray','LightSlateGrey','LightSteelBlue','LightYellow','Lime','LimeGreen','Linen','Magenta','Maroon','MediumAquaMarine','MediumBlue','MediumOrchid','MediumPurple','MediumSeaGreen','MediumSlateBlue','MediumSpringGreen','MediumTurquoise','MediumVioletRed','MidnightBlue','MintCream','MistyRose','Moccasin','NavajoWhite','Navy','OldLace','Olive','OliveDrab','Orange','OrangeRed','Orchid','PaleGoldenRod','PaleGreen','PaleTurquoise','PaleVioletRed','PapayaWhip','PeachPuff','Peru','Pink','Plum','PowderBlue','Purple','RebeccaPurple','Red','RosyBrown','RoyalBlue','SaddleBrown','Salmon','SandyBrown','SeaGreen','SeaShell','Sienna','Silver','SkyBlue','SlateBlue','SlateGray','SlateGrey','Snow','SpringGreen','SteelBlue','Tan','Teal','Thistle','Tomato','Turquoise','Violet','Wheat','White','WhiteSmoke','Yellow','YellowGreen']; }
  if (x == "hexs") {return ['f0f8ff','faebd7','00ffff','7fffd4','f0ffff','f5f5dc','ffe4c4','000000','ffebcd','0000ff','8a2be2','a52a2a','deb887','5f9ea0','7fff00','d2691e','ff7f50','6495ed','fff8dc','dc143c','00ffff','00008b','008b8b','b8860b','a9a9a9','a9a9a9','006400','bdb76b','8b008b','556b2f','ff8c00','9932cc','8b0000','e9967a','8fbc8f','483d8b','2f4f4f','2f4f4f','00ced1','9400d3','ff1493','00bfff','696969','696969','1e90ff','b22222','fffaf0','228b22','ff00ff','dcdcdc','f8f8ff','ffd700','daa520','808080','808080','008000','adff2f','f0fff0','ff69b4','cd5c5c','4b0082','fffff0','f0e68c','e6e6fa','fff0f5','7cfc00','fffacd','add8e6','f08080','e0ffff','fafad2','d3d3d3','d3d3d3','90ee90','ffb6c1','ffa07a','20b2aa','87cefa','778899','778899','b0c4de','ffffe0','00ff00','32cd32','faf0e6','ff00ff','800000','66cdaa','0000cd','ba55d3','9370db','3cb371','7b68ee','00fa9a','48d1cc','c71585','191970','f5fffa','ffe4e1','ffe4b5','ffdead','000080','fdf5e6','808000','6b8e23','ffa500','ff4500','da70d6','eee8aa','98fb98','afeeee','db7093','ffefd5','ffdab9','cd853f','ffc0cb','dda0dd','b0e0e6','800080','663399','ff0000','bc8f8f','4169e1','8b4513','fa8072','f4a460','2e8b57','fff5ee','a0522d','c0c0c0','87ceeb','6a5acd','708090','708090','fffafa','00ff7f','4682b4','d2b48c','008080','d8bfd8','ff6347','40e0d0','ee82ee','f5deb3','ffffff','f5f5f5','ffff00','9acd32']; }
}
function roundDecimals(c) {
  c.red = Number(c.red.toFixed(0));
  c.green = Number(c.green.toFixed(0));
  c.blue = Number(c.blue.toFixed(0));
  c.hue = Number(c.hue.toFixed(0));
  c.sat = Number(c.sat.toFixed(2));
  c.lightness = Number(c.lightness.toFixed(2));
  c.whiteness = Number(c.whiteness.toFixed(2));
  c.blackness = Number(c.blackness.toFixed(2));
  c.cyan = Number(c.cyan.toFixed(2));  
  c.magenta = Number(c.magenta.toFixed(2));
  c.yellow = Number(c.yellow.toFixed(2));
  c.black = Number(c.black.toFixed(2));
  c.ncol = c.ncol.substr(0, 1) + Math.round(Number(c.ncol.substr(1)));
  c.opacity = Number(c.opacity.toFixed(2));
  return c;
}
function hslToRgb(hue, sat, light) {
  var t1, t2, r, g, b;
  hue = hue / 60;
  if ( light <= 0.5 ) {
    t2 = light * (sat + 1);
  } else {
    t2 = light + sat - (light * sat);
  }
  t1 = light * 2 - t2;
  r = hueToRgb(t1, t2, hue + 2) * 255;
  g = hueToRgb(t1, t2, hue) * 255;
  b = hueToRgb(t1, t2, hue - 2) * 255;
  return {r : r, g : g, b : b};
}
function hueToRgb(t1, t2, hue) {
  if (hue < 0) hue += 6;
  if (hue >= 6) hue -= 6;
  if (hue < 1) return (t2 - t1) * hue + t1;
  else if(hue < 3) return t2;
  else if(hue < 4) return (t2 - t1) * (4 - hue) + t1;
  else return t1;
}
function hwbToRgb(hue, white, black) {
  var i, rgb, rgbArr = [], tot;
  rgb = hslToRgb(hue, 1, 0.50);
  rgbArr[0] = rgb.r / 255;
  rgbArr[1] = rgb.g / 255;
  rgbArr[2] = rgb.b / 255;
  tot = white + black;
  if (tot > 1) {
    white = Number((white / tot).toFixed(2));
    black = Number((black / tot).toFixed(2));
  }
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    rgbArr[i] *= (1 - (white) - (black));
    rgbArr[i] += (white);
    rgbArr[i] = Number(rgbArr[i] * 255);
  }
  return {r : rgbArr[0], g : rgbArr[1], b : rgbArr[2] };
}
function cmykToRgb(c, m, y, k) {
  var r, g, b;
  r = 255 - ((Math.min(1, c * (1 - k) + k)) * 255);
  g = 255 - ((Math.min(1, m * (1 - k) + k)) * 255);
  b = 255 - ((Math.min(1, y * (1 - k) + k)) * 255);
  return {r : r, g : g, b : b};
}
function ncolToRgb(ncol, white, black) {
  var letter, percent, h, w, b;
  h = ncol;
  if (isNaN(ncol.substr(0,1))) {
    letter = ncol.substr(0,1).toUpperCase();
    percent = ncol.substr(1);
    if (percent == "") {percent = 0;}
    percent = Number(percent);
    if (isNaN(percent)) {return false;}
    if (letter == "R") {h = 0 + (percent * 0.6);}
    if (letter == "Y") {h = 60 + (percent * 0.6);}
    if (letter == "G") {h = 120 + (percent * 0.6);}
    if (letter == "C") {h = 180 + (percent * 0.6);}
    if (letter == "B") {h = 240 + (percent * 0.6);}
    if (letter == "M") {h = 300 + (percent * 0.6);}
    if (letter == "W") {
      h = 0;
      white = 1 - (percent / 100);
      black = (percent / 100);
    }
  }
  return hwbToRgb(h, white, black);
}
function hueToNcol(hue) {
  while (hue >= 360) {
    hue = hue - 360;
  }
  if (hue < 60) {return "R" + (hue / 0.6); }
  if (hue < 120) {return "Y" + ((hue - 60) / 0.6); }
  if (hue < 180) {return "G" + ((hue - 120) / 0.6); }
  if (hue < 240) {return "C" + ((hue - 180) / 0.6); }
  if (hue < 300) {return "B" + ((hue - 240) / 0.6); }
  if (hue < 360) {return "M" + ((hue - 300) / 0.6); }
}
function ncsToRgb(ncs){
  var black, chroma, bc, percent, black1, chroma1, red1, factor1, blue1, red1, red2, green2, blue2, max, factor2, grey, r, g, b; 
  ncs = w3trim(ncs).toUpperCase();
  ncs = ncs.replace("(", "");
  ncs = ncs.replace(")", "");
  ncs = ncs.replace("NCS", "NCS ");
  ncs = ncs.replace(/  /g, " ");  
  if (ncs.indexOf("NCS") == -1) {ncs = "NCS " + ncs;}
  ncs = ncs.match(/^(?:NCS|NCS\sS)\s(\d{2})(\d{2})-(N|[A-Z])(\d{2})?([A-Z])?$/);
  if (ncs === null) return false;
  black = parseInt(ncs[1], 10);
  chroma = parseInt(ncs[2], 10);
  bc = ncs[3];
  if (bc != "N" && bc != "Y" && bc != "R" && bc != "B" && bc != "G") {return false;}
  percent = parseInt(ncs[4], 10) || 0;
  if (bc !== 'N') {
    black1 = (1.05 * black - 5.25);
    chroma1 = chroma;
    if (bc === 'Y' && percent <= 60) {
      red1 = 1;
    } else if (( bc === 'Y' && percent > 60) || ( bc === 'R' && percent <= 80)) {
      if (bc === 'Y') {
        factor1 = percent - 60;
      } else {
        factor1 = percent + 40;
      }
      red1 = ((Math.sqrt(14884 - Math.pow(factor1, 2))) - 22) / 100;
    } else if ((bc === 'R' && percent > 80) || (bc === 'B')) {
      red1 = 0;
    } else if (bc === 'G') {
      factor1 = (percent - 170);
      red1 = ((Math.sqrt(33800 - Math.pow(factor1, 2))) - 70) / 100;
    }
    if (bc === 'Y' && percent <= 80) {
      blue1 = 0;
    } else if (( bc === 'Y' && percent > 80) || ( bc === 'R' && percent <= 60)) {
      if (bc ==='Y') {
        factor1 = (percent - 80) + 20.5;
      } else {
        factor1 = (percent + 20) + 20.5;
      }
      blue1 = (104 - (Math.sqrt(11236 - Math.pow(factor1, 2)))) / 100;
    } else if ((bc === 'R' && percent > 60) || ( bc === 'B' && percent <= 80)) {
      if (bc ==='R') {
        factor1 = (percent - 60) - 60;
      } else {
        factor1 = (percent + 40) - 60;
      }
      blue1 = ((Math.sqrt(10000 - Math.pow(factor1, 2))) - 10) / 100;
    } else if (( bc === 'B' && percent > 80) || ( bc === 'G' && percent <= 40)) {
      if (bc === 'B') {
        factor1 = (percent - 80) - 131;
      } else {
        factor1 = (percent + 20) - 131;
      }
      blue1 = (122 - (Math.sqrt(19881 - Math.pow(factor1, 2)))) / 100;
    } else if (bc === 'G' && percent > 40) {
      blue1 = 0;
    }
    if (bc === 'Y') {
      green1 = (85 - 17/20 * percent) / 100;
    } else if (bc === 'R' && percent <= 60) {
      green1 = 0;
    } else if (bc === 'R' && percent > 60) {
      factor1 = (percent - 60) + 35;
      green1 = (67.5 - (Math.sqrt(5776 - Math.pow(factor1, 2)))) / 100;
    } else if (bc === 'B' && percent <= 60) {
      factor1 = (1*percent - 68.5);
      green1 = (6.5 + (Math.sqrt(7044.5 - Math.pow(factor1, 2)))) / 100;
    } else if ((bc === 'B' && percent > 60) || ( bc === 'G' && percent <= 60)) {
      green1 = 0.9;
    } else if (bc === 'G' && percent > 60) {
      factor1 = (percent - 60);
      green1 = (90 - (1/8 * factor1)) / 100;
    }
    factor1 = (red1 + green1 + blue1)/3;
    red2 = ((factor1 - red1) * (100 - chroma1) / 100) + red1;
    green2 = ((factor1 - green1) * (100 - chroma1) / 100) + green1;
    blue2 = ((factor1 - blue1) * (100 - chroma1) / 100) + blue1;
    if (red2 > green2 && red2 > blue2) {
      max = red2;
    } else if (green2 > red2 && green2 > blue2) {
      max = green2;
    } else if (blue2 > red2 && blue2 > green2) {
      max = blue2;
    } else {
      max = (red2 + green2 + blue2) / 3;
    }
    factor2 = 1 / max;
    r = parseInt((red2 * factor2 * (100 - black1) / 100) * 255, 10);
    g = parseInt((green2 * factor2 * (100 - black1) / 100) * 255, 10);
    b = parseInt((blue2 * factor2 * (100 - black1) / 100) * 255, 10);
    if (r > 255) {r = 255;}
    if (g > 255) {g = 255;}
    if (b > 255) {b = 255;}
    if (r < 0) {r = 0;}
    if (g < 0) {g = 0;}
    if (b < 0) {b = 0;}
  } else {
    grey = parseInt((1 - black / 100) * 255, 10);
    if (grey > 255) {grey = 255;}
    if (grey < 0) {grey = 0;}
    r = grey;
    g = grey;
    b = grey;
  }
  return {
    r : r,
    g : g,
    b : b
  };
}
function rgbToHsl(r, g, b) {
  var min, max, i, l, s, maxcolor, h, rgb = [];
  rgb[0] = r / 255;
  rgb[1] = g / 255;
  rgb[2] = b / 255;
  min = rgb[0];
  max = rgb[0];
  maxcolor = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < rgb.length - 1; i++) {
    if (rgb[i + 1] <= min) {min = rgb[i + 1];}
    if (rgb[i + 1] >= max) {max = rgb[i + 1];maxcolor = i + 1;}
  }
  if (maxcolor == 0) {
    h = (rgb[1] - rgb[2]) / (max - min);
  }
  if (maxcolor == 1) {
    h = 2 + (rgb[2] - rgb[0]) / (max - min);
  }
  if (maxcolor == 2) {
    h = 4 + (rgb[0] - rgb[1]) / (max - min);
  }
  if (isNaN(h)) {h = 0;}
  h = h * 60;
  if (h < 0) {h = h + 360; }
  l = (min + max) / 2;
  if (min == max) {
    s = 0;
  } else {
    if (l < 0.5) {
      s = (max - min) / (max + min);
    } else {
      s = (max - min) / (2 - max - min);
    }
  }
  s = s;
  return {h : h, s : s, l : l};
}
function rgbToHwb(r, g, b) {
  var h, w, bl;
  r = r / 255;
  g = g / 255;
  b = b / 255;
  max = Math.max(r, g, b);
  min = Math.min(r, g, b);
  chroma = max - min;
  if (chroma == 0) {
    h = 0;
  } else if (r == max) {
    h = (((g - b) / chroma) % 6) * 360;
  } else if (g == max) {
    h = ((((b - r) / chroma) + 2) % 6) * 360;
  } else {
    h = ((((r - g) / chroma) + 4) % 6) * 360;
  }
  w = min;
  bl = 1 - max;
  return {h : h, w : w, b : bl};
}
function rgbToCmyk(r, g, b) {
  var c, m, y, k;
  r = r / 255;
  g = g / 255;
  b = b / 255;
  max = Math.max(r, g, b);
  k = 1 - max;
  if (k == 1) {
    c = 0;
    m = 0;
    y = 0;
  } else {
    c = (1 - r - k) / (1 - k);
    m = (1 - g - k) / (1 - k);
    y = (1 - b - k) / (1 - k);
  }
  return {c : c, m : m, y : y, k : k};
}
function toHex(n) {
  var hex = n.toString(16);
  while (hex.length < 2) {hex = "0" + hex; }
  return hex;
}
function cl(x) {
  console.log(x);
}
function w3trim(x) {
  return x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
}
function isHex(x) {
  return ('0123456789ABCDEFabcdef'.indexOf(x) > -1);
}
window.w3color = w3color;

})();

function w3SetColorsByAttribute() {
  var z, i, att;
  z = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
  for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
    att = z[i].getAttribute("data-w3-color");
    if (att) {
      z[i].style.backgroundColor = w3color(att).toRgbString();      
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this project https://github.com/evansque/coloraze
and here is the node module for it https://www.npmjs.com/package/coloraze