# Get color name by HEX or RGB

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, colors

How can I get a color name using JS/JQuery, knowing the code RBG/HEX?

For example:

```
Colorname      RGB
black          #000000  
white          #FFFFFF
red            #FF0000
green          #008000
```

Comment: What should happen for colors that don't have a name, like `#020304`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert RGB to ColorName String Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486730/convert-rgb-to-colorname-string-javascript) (have a look @ http://chir.ag/projects/name-that-color)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### You can use [Name that Color](http://chir.ag/projects/ntc/).

**Example:**

```
let result = ntc.name('#6195ed');

let rgb_value = result[0];      // #6495ed         : RGB value of closest match
let specific_name = result[1];  // Cornflower Blue : Color name of closest match
let is_exact_match = result[2]; // false           : True if exact color match
```

---

There is also a variation of Name that Color that includes additional parameters:

http://www.color-blindness.com/color-name-hue-tool/js/ntc.js

**Example:**

```
let result = ntc.name('#6195ed');

let rgb_value = result[0];      // #6495ed         : RGB value of closest match
let specific_name = result[1];  // Cornflower Blue : Color name of closest match
let shade_value = result[2];    // #0000ff         : RGB value of shade of closest match
let shade_name = result[3];     // Blue            : Color name of shade of closest match
let is_exact_match = result[4]; // false           : True if exact color match
```

Answer (score 8):

You can do that with [color_classifier.js](http://gauth.fr/2011/09/get-a-color-name-from-any-rgb-combination/) plugin. It works good and returns the name of  **nearest** color that has name.

Just use like this

```
window.classifier = new ColorClassifier();
get_dataset('dataset.js', function (data){
    window.classifier.learn(data);
});
var result_name = window.classifier.classify("#aaf000");
```

Answer (score 7):

First create a function to convert the rgb color to hsl:

```
function hsl(rgbArr) {
  var r1 = Number(rgbArr[0]) / 255, g1 = Number(rgbArr[1]) / 255, b1 = Number(rgbArr[2]) / 255;
  var maxColor = Math.max(r1,g1,b1), minColor = Math.min(r1,g1,b1);
  var L = (maxColor + minColor) / 2 , S = 0, H = 0;
  if(maxColor != minColor){
    if(L < 0.5){
      S = (maxColor - minColor) / (maxColor + minColor);
    }else{
      S = (maxColor - minColor) / (2.0 - maxColor - minColor);
    }
    if(r1 == maxColor){
      H = (g1-b1) / (maxColor - minColor);
    }else if(g1 == maxColor){
      H = 2.0 + (b1 - r1) / (maxColor - minColor);
    }else{
      H = 4.0 + (r1 - g1) / (maxColor - minColor);
    }
  }
  L = L * 100;
  S = S * 100;
  H = H * 60;
  if(H<0){
    H += 360;
  }
  return {h:H, s:S, l:L};
}
```

Create a function to clasific the colors:

```
function colorName(hsl) {
        var l = Math.floor(hsl.l), s = Math.floor(hsl.s), h = Math.floor(hsl.h);
        if (s <= 10 && l >= 90) {
            return ("White")
        } else if (l <= 15) {
            return ("Black")
        } else if ((s <= 10 && l <= 70) || s === 0) {
            return ("Gray")
        } else if ((h >= 0 && h <= 15) || h >= 346) {
            return ("Red");
        } else if (h >= 16 && h <= 35) {
            if (s < 90) {
                return ("Brown");
            } else {
                return ("Orange");
            }
        } else if (h >= 36 && h <= 54) {
            if (s < 90) {
                return ("Brown");
            } else {
                return ("Yellow");
            }
        } else if (h >= 55 && h <= 165) {
            return ("Green");
        } else if (h >= 166 && h <= 260) {
            return ("Blue")
        } else if (h >= 261 && h <= 290) {
            return ("Purple")
        } else if (h >= 291 && h <= 345) {
            return ("Pink")
        }
    }
```

And a function to get the intensity of color:

```
function inten(rgb){
  var hex = "",hex += Number(rgb[0]).toString(16), hex += Number(rgb[1]).toString(16), hex += Number(rgb[2]).toString(16), txt = "";
  var rgb = parseInt(hex, 16);
  var r = (rgb >> 16) & 0xff; 
  var g = (rgb >>  8) & 0xff;
  var b = (rgb >>  0) & 0xff; 
  var inten = 0.2126 * r + 0.7152 * g + 0.0722 * b;
  if(inten >= 80 && inten <= 100){
    txt = "semi dark";
  }    else if(inten < 40){
    txt = "dark";
  }    else{
    txt = "light";
  }
 return txt;
}
```

**Example:**

```
var color = "rgb(253, 209, 57)";
var rgb = color.replace(/[^0-9,]/g,'').replace().split(",");
var nameColor = colorName(hsl(rgb))+" "+inten(rgb);
console.log(nameColor);
```

Answer (score 6):

This color range was created by using specific query selector on [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_names.asp)

> It might be useful if you writing jQuery plugin or something else without npm and you want to avoid third party libraries

```
JSON.stringify(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.colorbox')).map((el) => ({
    [el.querySelector('.colornamespan > a').innerText.toLowerCase()]: el.querySelector('.colorhexspan > a').innerText.toLowerCase()
})).reduce((acm, cur) => ({...acm, ...cur}), {}));
```

[image: w3schools]

```
const wordToHex = {
    aliceblue: "#F0F8FF",
    antiquewhite: "#FAEBD7",
    aqua: "#00FFFF",
    aquamarine: "#7FFFD4",
    azure: "#F0FFFF",
    beige: "#F5F5DC",
    bisque: "#FFE4C4",
    black: "#000000",
    blanchedalmond: "#FFEBCD",
    blue: "#0000FF",
    blueviolet: "#8A2BE2",
    brown: "#A52A2A",
    burlywood: "#DEB887",
    cadetblue: "#5F9EA0",
    chartreuse: "#7FFF00",
    chocolate: "#D2691E",
    coral: "#FF7F50",
    cornflowerblue: "#6495ED",
    cornsilk: "#FFF8DC",
    crimson: "#DC143C",
    cyan: "#00FFFF",
    darkblue: "#00008B",
    darkcyan: "#008B8B",
    darkgoldenrod: "#B8860B",
    darkgray: "#A9A9A9",
    darkgrey: "#A9A9A9",
    darkgreen: "#006400",
    darkkhaki: "#BDB76B",
    darkmagenta: "#8B008B",
    darkolivegreen: "#556B2F",
    darkorange: "#FF8C00",
    darkorchid: "#9932CC",
    darkred: "#8B0000",
    darksalmon: "#E9967A",
    darkseagreen: "#8FBC8F",
    darkslateblue: "#483D8B",
    darkslategray: "#2F4F4F",
    darkslategrey: "#2F4F4F",
    darkturquoise: "#00CED1",
    darkviolet: "#9400D3",
    deeppink: "#FF1493",
    deepskyblue: "#00BFFF",
    dimgray: "#696969",
    dimgrey: "#696969",
    dodgerblue: "#1E90FF",
    firebrick: "#B22222",
    floralwhite: "#FFFAF0",
    forestgreen: "#228B22",
    fuchsia: "#FF00FF",
    gainsboro: "#DCDCDC",
    ghostwhite: "#F8F8FF",
    gold: "#FFD700",
    goldenrod: "#DAA520",
    gray: "#808080",
    grey: "#808080",
    green: "#008000",
    greenyellow: "#ADFF2F",
    honeydew: "#F0FFF0",
    hotpink: "#FF69B4",
    indianred: "#CD5C5C",
    indigo: "#4B0082",
    ivory: "#FFFFF0",
    khaki: "#F0E68C",
    lavender: "#E6E6FA",
    lavenderblush: "#FFF0F5",
    lawngreen: "#7CFC00",
    lemonchiffon: "#FFFACD",
    lightblue: "#ADD8E6",
    lightcoral: "#F08080",
    lightcyan: "#E0FFFF",
    lightgoldenrodyellow: "#FAFAD2",
    lightgray: "#D3D3D3",
    lightgrey: "#D3D3D3",
    lightgreen: "#90EE90",
    lightpink: "#FFB6C1",
    lightsalmon: "#FFA07A",
    lightseagreen: "#20B2AA",
    lightskyblue: "#87CEFA",
    lightslategray: "#778899",
    lightslategrey: "#778899",
    lightsteelblue: "#B0C4DE",
    lightyellow: "#FFFFE0",
    lime: "#00FF00",
    limegreen: "#32CD32",
    linen: "#FAF0E6",
    magenta: "#FF00FF",
    maroon: "#800000",
    mediumaquamarine: "#66CDAA",
    mediumblue: "#0000CD",
    mediumorchid: "#BA55D3",
    mediumpurple: "#9370DB",
    mediumseagreen: "#3CB371",
    mediumslateblue: "#7B68EE",
    mediumspringgreen: "#00FA9A",
    mediumturquoise: "#48D1CC",
    mediumvioletred: "#C71585",
    midnightblue: "#191970",
    mintcream: "#F5FFFA",
    mistyrose: "#FFE4E1",
    moccasin: "#FFE4B5",
    navajowhite: "#FFDEAD",
    navy: "#000080",
    oldlace: "#FDF5E6",
    olive: "#808000",
    olivedrab: "#6B8E23",
    orange: "#FFA500",
    orangered: "#FF4500",
    orchid: "#DA70D6",
    palegoldenrod: "#EEE8AA",
    palegreen: "#98FB98",
    paleturquoise: "#AFEEEE",
    palevioletred: "#DB7093",
    papayawhip: "#FFEFD5",
    peachpuff: "#FFDAB9",
    peru: "#CD853F",
    pink: "#FFC0CB",
    plum: "#DDA0DD",
    powderblue: "#B0E0E6",
    purple: "#800080",
    rebeccapurple: "#663399",
    red: "#FF0000",
    rosybrown: "#BC8F8F",
    royalblue: "#4169E1",
    saddlebrown: "#8B4513",
    salmon: "#FA8072",
    sandybrown: "#F4A460",
    seagreen: "#2E8B57",
    seashell: "#FFF5EE",
    sienna: "#A0522D",
    silver: "#C0C0C0",
    skyblue: "#87CEEB",
    slateblue: "#6A5ACD",
    slategray: "#708090",
    slategrey: "#708090",
    snow: "#FFFAFA",
    springgreen: "#00FF7F",
    steelblue: "#4682B4",
    tan: "#D2B48C",
    teal: "#008080",
    thistle: "#D8BFD8",
    tomato: "#FF6347",
    turquoise: "#40E0D0",
    violet: "#EE82EE",
    wheat: "#F5DEB3",
    white: "#FFFFFF",
    whitesmoke: "#F5F5F5",
    yellow: "#FFFF00",
    yellowgreen: "#9ACD32",
};

const hexToWord =  Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(wordToHex).map(([k, v]) => [v, k]))

const toHex = (color) => wordToHex[color.toLowerCase()];
const fromHex = (hex) => hexToWord[hex.toLowerCase()];
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you can see RGB and corresponding color names:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colornames.asp

How you can use It depends on your application, you can store It in a database or may hardcoding It.