# Get color code from color word

Tags: javascript, css, colors

I would like to write a javascript program to get the rgb color for the defined color words in css.

So for example, if I type in `red`, I would like to output `rgb(255, 0, 0)`.  I would also like to convert from `rgb(255, 0, 0)` to `red`.

Is there a way to do this in javascript?

Comment: Not my downvote. rgb(51, 51, 51) is (a bit dark) grey. Red is 255,0,0

Comment: well, the easiest and most reliable way would surely be to have a mapping object to map all colors to all rgb values.

Comment: `rgb(51, 51, 51)` is grey. RGB is an abbreviation of Red Green Blue. `rgb(red, green, blue)`. Red, therefore, is `rgb(255, 0, 0)`.

Comment: Half of your question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573053/javascript-function-to-convert-color-names-to-hex-codes

Comment: @Christoph yes but I want to do it programmatically

Comment: And here is the other half: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224404/get-color-name-by-hex-or-rgb (marking as duplicate)

Comment: @SalmanA note, that the color classifier lists color which are not available in the browser! The webcolors are: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-color/#svg-color while there are a lot more colors available for "non-web": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_colors

Comment: @Scoop i added an example with a complete map of colors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can't be accomplished *easily* programatically, because browsers differ in their behaviour. You can't say for sure whether they return the original value (e.g. your word) or the computed hex or rgb value.  (It is possible, though with `getComputedStyle()`!)

In every case you *won't* get the color word for your rgb/hex/hsl value. (At least I'm not aware of this being possible).

The "easiest", reliable way would be to create a mapping object which hold all color words and their respective values. You can find the list here:

http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-color/#svg-color

```
var word2value = {
       red: {"hex":"#FF0000","rgb":"255,0,0"},
       /* ... all other values */
}

var value2word = {
       "FF0000" : "red",
       "255,0,0": "red"
}
```

note, you need to access via bracket notation: `value2word["255,0,0"]`

Comment: That's definetly the most reliable way. +1 because it supports both ways

Answer (score 2):

You could

- create a new Element using javascript.
- set its background-color o.s. style to the input value
- append it to the body
- get its [`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle) *note: compatibility*
- return the equivalent `backgroundColor` o.s.

---

```
function getRGB(v) {
    var el = document.createElement("div");
    el.style["background-color"] = v;
    document.body.appendChild(el);

    var style = window.getComputedStyle(el);

    var color = style["backgroundColor"];

    document.body.removeChild(el);
    return color;

}

getRGB ("red") //"rgb(255, 0, 0)"
```

*But note: as Cristoph says you can't say for sure to always get the right value*
*Though it works quite well for me on Chrome*

But i don't think you can get it the other way round with out a Map, like Cristoph suggests

**Demon on [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/okacap/3/edit)**

## Update

---

Here is a function with a complete map which returns color Objects that contain hex,named,and rgb represantations of the color.

```
function getColor (r,g,b) {

var colors = {TooBigToPostHere:...}     //see the JSBin                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
     var hex = "#";
     for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
         var _hex = arguments[i].toString(16);
         while (_hex.length < 2) _hex = "0" + _hex;
         hex += _hex
     }
     return hex.toUpperCase();
 }
 if (typeof r === "string")  r = r["to"+(!!~r.indexOf("#")?"Upper":"Lower")+"Case"]();   
 if (r in colors) return colors[r]
 else if (r !== undefined && g !== undefined && b !== undefined) {
     var hex = rgbToHex(r, g, b);
     if (hex in colors) return colors[hex]
     else return {
             rgb: [r, g, b],
             hex: hex,
             name: null
     }
 } else {
     throw new SyntaxError("Invalid Arguments");
 }

}
```

Which produces this output:

```
console.log ( getColor (245,245,245)) //{"hex": "#F5F5F5", "name": "whitesmoke", "rgb": [245, 245, 245]}
console.log ( getColor ("#EE82EE")); //{"hex": "#EE82EE", "name": "violet", "rgb": [238, 130, 238]}
console.log ( getColor ("red")); //{"hex": "#FF0000", "name": "red", "rgb": [255, 0, 0]}
```

And a **Demo on [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ikibah/3/edit)**
*Note: colors contains the complete list of [Extended color keywords](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-color/#svg-color)*

Heres the code i used to scrape the above color table

```
var colors = {};
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll (".colortable tr"), function (e,i) {
if ( i > 0 ) {
 var hex = e.children[3].innerText;
 colors[hex] = {};
 colors[hex].hex = hex;
 colors[hex].name = e.children[2].innerText;
 colors[hex].rgb = e.children[4].innerText.split(",");
 colors[hex].rgb.map(function (a,b,c) {c[b] = +a})
 colors[colors[hex].name] = colors[hex];
 }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want:

```
Text:
<input type="text" id="ctext" />
<br>RGB:
<input type="text" id="crgb" />
<br>
<button onclick="doMagic();">Magic</button>
<div id="output" style="display:none"></div>
<script>
    function doMagic() {
        $('#output').html('<p id=test style=\'color:' + $('#ctext').val() + ';\'>sometext</p>');
        $('#crgb').val($('#test').css("color"));
    }
</script>
```

Check it out on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TMCby/3/) .

I think it works great!

Comment: What about the other way around?