# convert hex values into color names in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a colour field in form, it saves the colour name as hex value. I want to display the colour name in index and show page. How to convert hex values into colour names? I use gem 'jquery-minicolors-rails'.
In form,

```
<%= f.color_field :syllab_color, :id => 'Color' %>
```

in index and show page,

```
<%= @syllab.syllab_color.to_s %>
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by color name? Like `red`, `blue`? I'm 90% sure about this, I don't think every hex value has a name on it, so you might probably need to be satisfied with the hex value prepended by `#`.

Comment: When I pick colour from field it saves like #d57df0. Now I want display the hex value as colour name.

Comment: Can you give an example of colour name? Or is it as `colour_name` field?

Comment: If I select  #f0f8ff from colour picker, I want to convert it into "Alice Blue", the corresponding colour name

Comment: Ahh, then this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486730/convert-rgb-to-colorname-string-javascript

Comment: If normal hex value conversion, we can use .to_s(16) or to_byte_string etc. Is there any possible ways?

Answer (score 0):

jquery-minicolors-rails has a lot of useful colour manipulation methods, but does not contain a database for colour names. 
Lots of colours do have names assigned to them e.g. [Wikipedia List of colors:A-F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_colors:_A%E2%80%93F), but you would have to find or create a database listing them.

And as [Ace Dimasuhid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1825484/ace-dimasuhid) mentioned, not every 24-bit colour has a named assigned to it. I think only a few thousand out of 16million+ colours have names, so you may consider writing an algorithm to find the nearest named colours to a given unnamed hex value.

[ColorHexa](https://www.colorhexa.com/) does this very well.