# Returning name of colors using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, web

CSS:

```
.red-tile-color{
    background-color:red;
    color:white;
}
```

JS:

```
var colorName = $(".red-tile-color").css("color");
```

Return:

```
rgb(255, 255, 255);
```

How do i return the **name** of color assigned on css?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need it?

Comment: I need a reference of the color name to choose which image would i use: eg. img_white or img_black! got it?

Comment: It may help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/3892864/1378877

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to be messy trying to get a name from the rgb value. I would instead encourage you to use the [jQuery Color plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) to determine whether the current color is a particular value or not:

```
if ( $.Color( colorName ).is( "red" ) ) {
    /* Do X */
} else {
    /* Do Y */
}
```