# How to obtain css property value of an item in a select using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to fetch the color of a list item on clicking it. I want to put some constraint on it when the color is red, say. How to do it,I am not getting it.

```
if($("#listbox option:selected").css("color")=="red"){
}
```

I have a listbox with some items of red color. I want to stop user from selecting those red color items.

Please help me.

Comment: can you share the html??

Comment: Depend on how you style the options. Is it inline css?

Comment: @Aamir Afridi actually the css is attached dynamically using jquery. it is not in static code.

Comment: @edge: can you share the relevant code or link/

Comment: Try http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/tq9W8/1/

Comment: `.css('color')` will give you an rgb value, try adding data attributes to your option and use that instead - http://jsfiddle.net/SMLUS/

Comment: @Aamir it does not work , if there is no item with red at beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Pete suggested, use data attribute which is better and easy way: http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/tq9W8/5/

```
$('#listbox option:eq(0)').css('color', 'red').data('color', 'red');

$('#listbox').change(function () {
    if ($(this).find("option:selected").data('color') == 'red') {
        alert('color is red');
    } else {
        alert('other options');
    }
});
```

or you can try this: http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/tq9W8/4/

```
$('#listbox option:eq(0)').css('color', 'red');

function checkColorByName(ele, colorName) {
    var tempDiv = $('<div>').css("color", colorName).hide().appendTo('body');
    console.log(tempDiv.css('color'));
    var bol = tempDiv.css('color') == ele.css('color');
    tempDiv.remove();
    return bol;
}


$('#listbox').change(function () {
    if (checkColorByName($(this).find("option:selected"), 'red')) {
        alert('color is red');
    } else {
        alert('other options');
    }
});
```

Other wise according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10778397/returning-name-of-colors-using-jquery), you need to use a [plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color).

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740700/how-to-get-hex-color-value-rather-than-rgb-value

Answer (score 0):

Your code is good.

If it's not working, do `console.log($("#listbox option:selected").css("color")=="red");`

If it says undefined, the color attribute is not set on the option, but maybe on the `#listbox`.
(Try `$("#listbox option:selected").parent().css("color")=="red")`)

Comment: He to find a way to get option color and compare with the color name. read my answer for details and also Pete detail under the question :)