# Determining the background-color or color in numeric format across browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been through a number of responses to similar questions. I just want to clarify if I am understanding correctly. My purpose is to do some colour calculations.

I have been working in fire fox where:

```
var bkg_Colour = $("#test_Box_1").css("background-color");  // is red
var fgd_Colour = $("#test_Box_2").css("background-color");  // is blue
```

returns rgb(255, 0, 0) and rgb(0, 0, 255) respectively.

Which is fine and I have calculated the distance between the foreground and background appropriately by splitting out the tuples and comparing them.

**BUT:**

In internet explorer this same code returns "red" and "blue" and of course the calculation fails.

Form the previous answers it appears that there isn't a consistent way of getting the colour back (whether background-color or color) in a numeric format - if using $(...).css. And it appears that all sorts of hoops have to jumped through to cover all the bases.

So is there a way of doing this without using $(...).css?

**Edit**

Just following this up when I apply the example code given [here](http://api.jquery.com/css/)  in my script and I run it in FF I get rgb(255,0,0) when I run it in IE i see the word "red" in result. **BUT**
when I run the above link in IE result is rgb(xxx,xx,xx) I am therefore very confused. Is there a server setting or something that is causing IE to behave this way on the page I am serving??

**Edit**

As far as I can tell at the moment in IE it reports back the colour as specified in the css, namely "green" "blue" "red" or #808080 etc. whereas in ff it always reports it back as a rgb value.

Comment: Check out this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eliranmal/5WJT2/. Seems to work in IE to give you a hex value. This can then be converted to rgb(a) -> http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/convert-hex-to-rgb/

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question. You're looking for a consistent way to get the background-color in rgb?

Comment: Well in any numeric format. rgb is fine. I looked at the fiddle and it works. I am just trying to see what you did differently to me.

Comment: jQuery maintains a plugin used for this, [jQuery Color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color/)

Comment: IF you change the fiddle #xxxxx to "green" you get back the "green"...in IE8 at least

Comment: To answer your server setting question.  It's all done with JavaScript in the browser (client-side)... none of this has anything to do with your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are going to have to resort to a color names dictionary.  This is similar to this question: [Javascript function to convert color names to hex codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573053/javascript-function-to-convert-color-names-to-hex-codes) in concept at least.

Comment: Hi do you happen to know if that is an exhaustive standard list. It looks fairly comprehensive. I think that you are correct I am going to have to allow for the the query returning the color as rgb(255,255,255) or #ffffff or white. There are some examples around for doing this. I just thought that if there was a way to standardise what was returned by .css("background-color") that this could be avoided.

Comment: I don't know if it is complete or not, basically it returns the property value (string, etc) so "light blue" or some other text might be the value returned from the object.  This is simply interpreted by the browsers to come up with some actual displayed color and might even be different depending on that.