# Name of hex color code

Tags: hex, color-codes

I have a very stupid question. I know that there are different typs of color codes, for example for black there is:

0x000000

#000

but I do not know how these color codes are called? I know it is a hex code, but do they have a specific name? So someone knows from which one you are talking?

Thanks-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly I'd normally refer to the above as an RGB colour code. Values of red, green and blue in a scale of 0-FF expressed in hex, or 0-255 in decimal. The W3C organisation seem to refer to them that way as well:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/colors.html

Answer (score 1):

Not all colors have specific name. Some common colors have name. And how the name will be translated to a hex code depends on the parser. For example, CSS colors are parsed by css parser. HTML colors (bgcolor etc attribute) are parsed by html parser. Desktop environments (e.g. Gnome) also support named color.

You'll find all the color names on Wikipedia article [Web Colors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors). There are [HTML Colors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#HTML_color_names), [X11 Colors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#X11_color_names). Most modern web browser supports X11 Colors.

> a number of colors are defined by web browsers. A particular browser may not recognize all of these colors, but **as of 2005 all modern general-use browsers support the full list of colors**. Many of these colors are from the list of X11 color names distributed with the X Window System. These colors were standardized by SVG 1.0, and are accepted by SVG Full user agents. They are not part of SVG Tiny.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of colors available to browsers here (just use color:NameOfColor instead of the hex code): http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colornames.asp

If you want to convert from the hex code to the color name, you can use the script found here: [Javascript function to convert color names to hex codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573053/javascript-function-to-convert-color-names-to-hex-codes)