# how can I convert string to hex color with javascript

Tags: javascript, string, colors, hex

I have a list of names, which are usually updating from sql, in html5 , is it possible to make same names same color with javascript or jquery...

I tried to convert string to hex but I could not convert its to color code.

Regards...

Comment: Can you please give an examples for a few "names"?

Comment: This makes no sense in its current form. Can you clarify what your situation is?

Comment: "Bill", "Joe", "Olivia"... but the names can be different...

Comment: @user2081672: What have those names got to do with colours? What colours do you want to use?

Comment: If you want to just convert color names to hex, you can refer 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573053/javascript-function-to-convert-color-names-to-hex-codes

Comment: So what color is Bill? If there was a Homer, would he be yellow!

Comment: it can be random color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, assuming you don't have any specific colours I have done this using a random colour generator function.

What you can do is loop your list of names, and for each new name store a new colour values in a dictionary. You can then check this dictionary for names you have already used and get that same colour.

For example:

Assuming your html is simply as follows:

```
<ul></ul>
```

You can use this javascript:

```
var names = [
    "Bill", "Joe", "Oliver", "Joe", "George", "Bill", "George", "John"];
var currentAssignments = {};

for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    var name = names[i];
    var colour = currentAssignments[name];
    if (!colour) {
        colour = GetRandomColour();
        currentAssignments[name] = colour;
    }
    var li = $("<li>").html(name).css("color", colour);
    $("ul").append(li);
}

function GetRandomColour() {
    return '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
}
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/musefan/V8NnQ/)

---

Alternatively, if you have a predefined array of colours (and assuming you are sure you have enough unique colours to cater for all names) you could do this:

```
var colours = ["#F00", "#0F0", "#00F"];
```

and replace the `GetRandomColour()` function as follows:

```
function GetRandomColour() {
    return colours.pop();
}
```

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/musefan/V8NnQ/1/)

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I'd do it.

Create a function that takes a name and spits out a random color, however it's not truly random as it uses the name to create the color, and as such it will always return the same color for the same name:

```
function nameToColor(name) {
    var n = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');
    var r = name.split('').map(function(e) {return n.indexOf(e);}).join('');
    var l = parseFloat( '0.'+ (r*r*1000).toString().replace(/^0/, ''));
    return '#'+Math.floor(l*16777215).toString(16);
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/NTask/3/)