# How can I get rgb (or hex) code from css color-name in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a canvas gauge plugin and I need to convert css color codes like *'pink'* and *'orange'* into RGB format.

I thought of setting some element to `background: pink;` and the getting that color back with `$('el').css('background');` [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/watson/NFeWm/) but I don't know if that would always return what i want and it seems weird anyway.

I am hoping there is some built in window method or something that can do this conversion for me without me having to include a big map-object for all the codes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript function to convert color names to hex codes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573053/javascript-function-to-convert-color-names-to-hex-codes)

Comment: @BrandonTilley he doesnt want to include a map object

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/watson/NFeWm/ this works ... ridiculous tho

Comment: @BrandonTilley yeah... not a duplicate, cuz id rather use the solution in my last comment

Comment: there is no easy way to do ... and as far as i know browsers give different values for color names some times (i believe i read that once  some where)

Comment: how many colors are you going to deal with? No reason to try and avoid the map object if instead you use a conversion script that is 5 times bigger!

Comment: @Christophe well maybe i will do the map, but i can get the code using the technique in the fiddle with a couple lines

Comment: @watson well, I thought you didn't like that one :-) btw I just tried it in IE 10...

Comment: @Christophe yea... i dont like it, but ill use it maybe, i was just hoping there was a built-in method i didn't know about to do this. :)

Comment: There's not a built in function for this, and there are cross browser issues as some older browsers will return hex, and some modern browsers rgba etc. I'd do it like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/SGjyL/1/ but note that basic colors with wide support will not return rgb but the color name in Chrome etc, so you might need a map as well. There are libraries to check the color format returned, and convert hex, hsl etc. to rgb.

Comment: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color/blob/master/jquery.color.js has some exciting code to parse the potential formats

Comment: @stevemarvell why not make your comment an answer?

Answer (score 1):

> I need to convert css color codes like 'pink' and 'orange' into RGB format [...] I am hoping there is some built in window method or something that can do this conversion for me without me having to include a big map-object for all the codes.

Yes, there is. The method you are looking for is `window.getComputedStyle()`

You can run through the following steps:

- create a standard `<div>`
- add the color to the *style object* of the `<div>`
- append the `<div>` to the **DOM**
- use `window.getComputedStyle()` to inspect the computed styles of the `<div>`

---

**Working Example:**

```js
const colorKeywordToRGB = (colorKeyword) => {

  // CREATE TEMPORARY ELEMENT
  let el = document.createElement('div');

  // APPLY COLOR TO TEMPORARY ELEMENT
  el.style.color = colorKeyword;

  // APPEND TEMPORARY ELEMENT
  document.body.appendChild(el);

  // RESOLVE COLOR AS RGB() VALUE
  let rgbValue = window.getComputedStyle(el).color;
  
  // REMOVE TEMPORARY ELEMENT
  document.body.removeChild(el);

  return rgbValue;
}

console.log('pink:', colorKeywordToRGB('pink'));
console.log('orange:', colorKeywordToRGB('orange'));
```

---

**Further Reading:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Comment: ``document.body.append(el)`` and ``el.remove()`` will do. Internet Explorer (which didn't have those methods) is dead.

Answer (score 0):

```
github.com/jquery/jquery-color/blob/master/jquery.color.js
```

may be the processing library you are after.

Comment: That code is twice as long as the plugin im building, id rather accept an answer that says "what you want is not possible, and your going to have to include a map object (which would only be ~ 100 or 200 lines)" Plus jquer.color only has support for around 20 color names, which is not enough.

Comment: I'm sure that you you update it and put in a pull request, but if it doesn't suit your purpose, maybe it would suit others.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no interest in blending or adjusting saturation or hue2rgb or any of the functions of jquery.color except the scanty 20 line map object at the end.