# Colors convert to rgba or hex in php

Tags: php, colors, hex, rgb

How to convert colors "blue" or "green" or other colors to rgb or hex in PHP?

hexdec or dechex no help me.

Comment: You can't magically convert that; Check out [this table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#Color_keywords) for conversion.

Comment: or check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1573141/1576996)

Comment: thanks, I found a way out of your proposed method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm... I think you should create array of colors

```
$colors = array('red' => '2550000', 'blue' => '000255000');
```

hexdec decode your numeric in another system, not names of colors.