# I need Hexa code for color when user select string in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need java-script function when user select color in form on submit console should display Hexa code for color that is selected from user.

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
 <select id="selectColor"> 
  <option selected="selected"></option>
  <option value="abc">Red</option>
  <option value="def">Green</option>
  <option value="hij">Yellow</option> 
  <option value="hij">Purple</option>
  <option value="hij">orange</option>
  <option value="hij">Blue</option>
  <option value="hij">Brown</option>                                                        
 </select>
```

Comment: The urgency for your need in code comes with the proof you've tried it yourself, else it doesn't seem urgent. In the meantime, [search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573053/javascript-function-to-convert-color-names-to-hex-codes) for it.

Comment: Post some JavaScript that you've tried for us to look at.

Comment: Why dont you set the value to the hex code?

Comment: <option value="futhexhere.">orange</option> write hexa for each colour in your code in value this what the form will pass the hex value... tell me if i missed something.

Comment: i can set value for color but how i will do javascript part...very new in JS

Comment: <script>
$( "#selectColor" ).change(function() {
console.log($(this).val()); // Must
});
</script>
Also include jquery in your page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
$( "#selectColor" ).change(function() {
console.log($(this).val());
});
</script>
```

Also include jquery in your page.

Comment: well defined for biggners thank you...