# How to get rgb color code of color 'white' in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want a javascript function which will take a color name as parameter and it returns the color rgb code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript function to convert color names to hex codes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573053/javascript-function-to-convert-color-names-to-hex-codes)

Comment: Although the OP is asking for RGB not hex. You could use the same principle in that linked answer and create a map for the rgb values. rgb(255,255,255) being white, etc. Unless the OP actually means hex, in which case, carry on. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the style to a html element, let's say the `<div id='d1'></div>`

then you could check the computed color:

```
    var d1 = document.getElementById('d1')
    var color = window.getComputedStyle(d1, null)['color']
```