# Hard coded colors in bing maps polygon

Tags: javascript, maps, bing-maps, bing

I having two color objects in javascript one having value as #ff0000 and other one as cyan.I can show the first object in bing maps polygon in following format

```
var options = {fillColor: new Microsoft.Maps.Color(100,a,b,c)};
```

here a,b,c referrs to R,G,B values of #ff0000 after conversion.But how can i convert cyan or similar colors if entered in the same manner like red,green,blue
with the above format

Answer (score 0):

The only option would be to use a lookup table. There is a good solution posted here: [Javascript function to convert color names to hex codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573053/javascript-function-to-convert-color-names-to-hex-codes)