# Display Name of Color on hover ( Currently Color Hex Code is displayed)

Tags: jquery, html, css, colorbox

There is a set of 19 Colors placed on a div.  when we hover on a color it displays corresponding color hex code instead i need to display Color name.

Here is a ScreenShot -  http://prntscr.com/8hlzw1

[image]

Comment: Use https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color plugin

Comment: can you add your html and js, telling how are you achieving the color display?

Comment: Here you can check the code - http://backup.weibsites.com/product/south-beach/   Color will be displayed on clicking layers menu

Comment: There was a similar issue. Check this post if you dont want to use any plugins.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573053/javascript-function-to-convert-color-names-to-hex-codes