# Change color of a div based on divs color background

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div that I need to change color based on a javascript if-statement. The check is being made by pressing the green divbox and if the background is set to green, the box should change to black background.

Note! I do not wish to use another solution. I am just looking for understanding why this particular solution does not work.

If you activate the lowest positioned function that does work without button click, you need to inactivate the first function.

```js
function changeColorOnReloadIfGreen() {
var x = document.getElementById('box-1');
if (x.style.backgroundColor == 'green') {
  x.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
 }
}

/*********************************************************/
/*
Just for reference, activating below
that changes box-1 to black works (without if-statement).
*/
/*********************************************************/
/*
var x = document.getElementById('box-1')
x.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
*/
```

```css
.box-1 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 30px 0px 0px 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box-1" class="box-1" onclick="changeColorOnReloadIfGreen()"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your code is not working is because you have `background-color` css in a class. Had it been as a inline css then it would have been detected using `x.style.backgroundColor`. So, what you can do is, create a new class `green` and check for the existence of this class and if this class is found add a new class `black` in the element.

```js
function changeColorOnReloadIfGreen(elem) {
var x = document.getElementById('box-1');
 if (x.classList.contains('green')) {
   x.classList.remove("green");
   x.classList.add("black");
 }
}
```

```css
.box-1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 30px 0px 0px 30px;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.black{
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="box-1" class="box-1 green" onclick="changeColorOnReloadIfGreen(this)"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

As you set the `background-color` in an external CSS, you need `getComputedStyle()` to get its value.

Furthermore, the returned value is in a `rgb()` format, so here is a sample that will work

```js
function changeColorOnReloadIfGreen() {
  var x = document.getElementById('box-1');
  var c = window.getComputedStyle(x).getPropertyValue('background-color');
  if (c == "rgb(0, 128, 0)") {
    x.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
  }
}

/*********************************************************/
/*
Just for reference, activating below
that changes box-1 to black works (without if-statement).
*/
/*********************************************************/
/*
var x = document.getElementById('box-1')
x.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
*/
```

```css
.box-1 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 30px 0px 0px 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box-1" class="box-1" onclick="changeColorOnReloadIfGreen()"></div>
```

---

If you really need to compare against named colors, like `green`, you need to do something like this:

- [Javascript function to convert color names to hex codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573053/javascript-function-to-convert-color-names-to-hex-codes)

Or do something like this

```js
function changeColorOnReloadIfGreen() {
  var x = document.getElementById('box-1');
  var c = window.getComputedStyle(x).getPropertyValue('background-color');  
  if (c == getNameColorAsRGB('green')) {
    x.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
  }
}

function getNameColorAsRGB(n) {
  var t = document.createElement('div');  
  t.style.backgroundColor = n;
  t.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(t);
  var r = window.getComputedStyle(t).getPropertyValue('background-color');
  t.remove();
  return r;
}


/*********************************************************/
/*
Just for reference, activating below
that changes box-1 to black works (without if-statement).
*/
/*********************************************************/
/*
var x = document.getElementById('box-1')
x.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
*/
```

```css
.box-1 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 30px 0px 0px 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box-1" class="box-1" onclick="changeColorOnReloadIfGreen()"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you set `background-color: green;` in a CSS class, JavaScript "can't find" the background-color property of your element; simply because there is none. So you can add the background-color to your element by adding `style="background-color: green;"` to your div:

```js
function changeColorOnReloadIfGreen() {
  var x = document.getElementById('box-1');
  if (x.style.backgroundColor == 'green') {
    x.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
  }
}

/*********************************************************/
/*
Just for reference, activating below
that changes box-1 to black works (without if-statement).
*/
/*********************************************************/
/*
var x = document.getElementById('box-1')
x.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
*/
```

```css
.box-1 {
  /**background-color: green;*/
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 30px 0px 0px 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box-1" class="box-1" onclick="changeColorOnReloadIfGreen()" style="background-color: green;"></div>
<!-- Simply add "background-color: green;" via inline style -->
```

---

Or add another class to your CSS code and "switch" classes with CSS:

```js
function changeColorOnReloadIfGreen() {
  var x = document.getElementById('box-1');
  if (x.className == 'box-1') {
    x.classList.remove('box-1');
    x.classList.add('box-2');
  }
}

/*********************************************************/
/*
Just for reference, activating below
that changes box-1 to black works (without if-statement).
*/
/*********************************************************/
/*
var x = document.getElementById('box-1')
x.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
*/
```

```css
.box-1 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 30px 0px 0px 30px;
}

.box-2 {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 30px 0px 0px 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box-1" class="box-1" onclick="changeColorOnReloadIfGreen()"></div>
```