# How do I get the hsla value of a named css color?

Tags: css

How do I convert css color name: `orange` to `hsla` value?

I am trying to get a lighter (or darker) version of a named css color (ie: `blue` becomes `hsla(whatever darker blue is)`

Comment: You can use chrome dev tool to do it.

Comment: i need to do it programmatically.

Comment: try looking at this: [Javascript function to convert color names to hex codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573053/javascript-function-to-convert-color-names-to-hex-codes)