# Can I find out the color scheme in the browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, browser

since it is possible to find out if the PC is in darkmode or not I would like to know if it is possible to find out which colorschemer the User has taken e.g. yellow, green, orange, blue, purple, violet? Because I would like to build a web page that adapts according to the color scheme set, at best exact color values would be good.

[Google Chrome Color Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFrax.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the specs, you can use [system colors](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/#css-system-colors). For example, the system default background would be `Canvas`, which you can use like this: `background-color: Canvas`.

Support isn't always great but that's what you're looking for.

[image]

Alternatively, you can also look at the user-agent stylesheets (browser defaults). For example [the one for safari](https://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css) defines a few CSS variables like `-apple-system-opaque-secondary-fill` or `-webkit-control-background`.

For more info on all this, there is this [great article](https://blog.jim-nielsen.com/2021/css-system-colors/)

---

If you need to obtain the values of these colors in CSS, you can always hack around like this:

```js
function getRgbForColorName(name) {
  const d = document.createElement("div")
  d.style.color = name
  document.body.appendChild(d)
  const rgb = window.getComputedStyle(d).color
  document.body.removeChild(d)
  return rgb
}

console.log('Canvas:', getRgbForColorName('Canvas'))
console.log('Highlight:', getRgbForColorName('Highlight'))
```

There are probably cleaner way of doing this. This is just a proof-of-concept. See this answer: [Javascript function to convert color names to hex codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573053/javascript-function-to-convert-color-names-to-hex-codes).

---

On MacOS, the "color" that can be set by the user is `SelectedItem` which isn't recognized by Chrome.

Comment: Likely you wouldn’t be able to read the exact values of the colors in JavaScript oand

Comment: @DanielA.White I added a way to do that in my answer, tho it's not the greatest.

Comment: Not all values are readable due to privacy

Comment: @DanielA.White That's probably true. Haven't tried many of them but I was surprised that it returned anything TBH (for that exact reason).