# Why is there clColor and gcColor in TMS Web Core?

Tags: delphi, tms, tms-web-core

When I look at the `Color` property options on any component in a TMS Web Core Project, there are colors that start with "cl", but then another batch of the same colors that start with "gc":

[image: Delphi TMS Web Core Colors]

Why are there "cl" and "gc" colors? What are the differences? They look the same.

Comment: My guess - standard Delphi colors + Web colors

Comment: [CSS knows color names, too](https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/Grafik/Farbe/Farbpaletten#Farbnamen) - that's surely why TMS opted to offer those instead of Delphi/Windows ones. The lists might even differ in content, amount and names.

Comment: @AmigoJack I see. Thank you. Do you know in which unit the gc colors are defined maybe so that I can go and look at what the difference is in the back between say `clBlue` and `gcBlue` or if it's exactly the same (just different name)?

Comment: Use [JS to get a CSS color's RGB value for its name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24366628/4299358). Delphi color constant's first 24 bit are also exactly its RGB value. List both, then compare. If I would use TMS (having their units) I'd answer each of your questions. Again, I suggest performing [`findstr /s /i /c:gcDarkGreen *.pas`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Findstr) (or `*.inc`) on a base path to scan all files recursively for a given ASCII text.

Comment: Use Search-Find in Files, check directories, point it to the TMS source folder, and search for `gcBlue =`. If nothing is found, repeat the search using `gcBlue :=`.