# Whats the diffrence between gcNull and clNone value to the Color property in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, colors, null, delphi-11-alexandria, tms-web-core

Adding `gcNull` or `clNone` value to the `Color` property on for example a `TWebPanel` has the same effect at runtime.

So my question is: In what scenario would one use `gcNull` instead of `clNone`? Or `clNone` instead of `gcNull`?

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77354358/why-is-there-clcolor-and-gccolor-in-tms-web-core