# Converting css color string to its hex representation

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, colors, background-color

Currenlty, I'm writing an app that displays some cards. Each card has its own color. These colors are received from the backend as strings (red, pink, aquamarine) or hexes (#212121, #FFF).

I have a way to determine, wheather the text on this colors background should be white or black. The problem is with colors passed as strings,

Is there a way to convert any css color into its hex representation?

Here is the function that determines text color for given background color in hex value:

```
getContrastColor(hex: string): string {
        var hexColor = hex.substring(1);
        const radix = 16;
        var r = parseInt(hexColor.substring(0, 2), radix);
        var g = parseInt(hexColor.substring(2, 4), radix);
        var b = parseInt(hexColor.substring(4, 6), radix);
        var yiq = (r * 299 + g * 587 + b * 114) / 1000;
        return yiq >= 130 ? 'black' : 'white';
    }
```

Comment: Note that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47355187/519413) in the duplicate by far the more extensible method to use.